# Limit of bounded sequence

Tags: calculus

Prove that: if $x_n \gt 0\forall n\in \mathbb N$ and if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x_{n +1}}{x_n} \lt 1$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n =0$
I don't know how to start, please help me.

Comment: Intuitively... $(x_n)$ is a decreasing sequence and bounded by $0$... does this say something about $(x_n)\rightarrow ??$

Comment: The same can be said about $\;\frac{n+1}n\;$, @PraphullaKoushik ...something else is lacking.

Comment: @DonAntonio :  for $\frac{n+1}{n}$ we do not have $lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{n+1}{n}<1$ we actually have $lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{n+1}{n}=1$.. so, the example which you have given does not fit into given condition...

Comment: I know my example's limit isn't less than one, @PraphullaKoushik : I meant your statement about hte seq. being decreagin *and* bounded by zero...

Comment: Duplicate of [Showing that $a_n \to 0$ if $a_n/a_{n+1} \to l > 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149216/showing-that-a-n-to-0-if-a-n-a-n1-to-l-1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Let $L=\lim x_{n+1}/x_n$. By definition of limit, there is $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|x_{n+1}/x_n -L|<(1-L)/2$. So if $n>N$ then $x_{n+1}/x_n<(1+L)/2$.

Comment: I can´t see how from this, I get that ${x_n}$ tends to 0 (zero) I am trying to figure it out, can you tell me another hint?

Comment: @DavidHernandez So if $n>N$ then $x_n<((1+L)/2)x_{n-1}<\cdots<((1+L)/2)^{n-N} x_N$. Note that $(1+L)/2<1$ and $N$ is fixed number.

Comment: thanks a lot :D I think I got it

Answer (score 0):

W.l.o.g. by ignoring the first few terms we have $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \le a < 1$ for all $n$.

Then $x_{n+1} \le a^n x_1 \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Also note, this method is how you prove the ratio test used in DonAntonio's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The exercise is easily solved with the help of infinite series:

$$\text{The series}\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\;\;\text{is a positive one}$$

and **we're given** that the ratio test renders the series convergent, so it must be

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$$