# Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of positive real number such that limit $A_{n+1}/A_n=r<1$, can we evaluate the limit of $A_n$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of positive real number such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}=r<1,
$$
can we evaluate the $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$?

Comment: Hint: this implies that the series $\sum A_n$ converges. What does this tell you about $\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n$?

Comment: yes n tends to infinite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing that $a_n \to 0$ if $a_n/a_{n+1} \to l > 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149216/showing-that-a-n-to-0-if-a-n-a-n1-to-l-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = r < 1$, we can select an $m$ such that $r < m < 1$.  The limit implies that there must exist an $s \in \mathbb{N}$ such that we have $\displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < m$ for all $n \geq s$.  In particular, $a_{s+1} < ma_s$.

Taking this a step further and applying the above, we also have $a_{s+2} < m a_{s+1} < m^2a_s$.  In general, $a_{s+k} < m^ka_s$.

What does this tell us about $a_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

---

**Note:**  This is essentially the beginning of the proof of the ratio test for the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum a_n$, where $a_n$ is a sequence as above.

Comment: yes n tens to infinit,,,,nd what about limit An?

Comment: You have twice been given information about the relationship of what you are given to convergence of the **series** (i.e. sum) and asked "what does that  tell you about the limit of the sequence- and you have twice responded "yes, n tends to infinity".  Yes, everyone knew that from the start!  The question is "if $\sum A_n$ converges, what must be true of the sequence $A_n$?"