# What's the limit of the sequence $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, exponentiation, factorial

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$$

I have a question: is it valid to use Stirling's Formula to prove convergence of the sequence?

Comment: "Valid" in what sense? If this were an assignment, that would depend on what you may or may not take for granted.  If you mean in the sense of a possible circular argument, I do not think that this limit is needed to derive Stirling's formula, so that would not be an issue.

Comment: Stirling's formula is really overkill here.  I suggest writing the numerator and denominator out as products of $n$ numbers and looking for an upper bound.

Comment: FWIW, the formula is hardly needed, given that the expression is a product of $n$ positive factors, all $\le1$, the smallest of which is $1/n$, hence $n!/n^n<1/n\to0$.

Comment: @anon: You could write that as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: In fact, if $a_n=n!/n^n$, then $\lim\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1/e$, so for sufficiently large $n$, $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1/2$, which implies $a_n<1/2^n$.  For proofs that $\lim\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1/e$, including one that uses Stirling's formula, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48897/power-series-with-the-coefficients-n-nn) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-n-sqrtnn).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579825/compute-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-dfracnnn

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904113/limit-cn-n-nn-as-n-goes-to-infinity

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are two distinct questions here. The first one in the title is what the limit actually is. This is easy to see by writing out the expression as a product of $n$ positive factors:
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{n}{n}\right).$$ Every one of the factors $k/n$, $k=1,2,3,\dots,n$, is less than or equal to $1$. Hence the product is $$\le\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot1\cdot1\cdots1=1/n.$$
But $1/n$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so by the Squeeze theorem so does the original expression.

The second question is whether or not it's allowed to use Stirling's formula to derive the limit, which I believe Arturo's comment covers: there is no apparent circularity, but in the context of classwork the answer depends on whether or not you've formally learned the formula and are allowed to use it as a given.

Answer (score 5):

We will first show that the sequence $x_n = \frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges. To do this, we will show that the sequence is both monotonic and bounded.

**Lemma 1:** $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing.

*Proof*. We can see this with some simple algebra:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{n+1}{n+1}\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n} \frac{n^n}{n^n} = \frac{n!}{n^n} \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} = x_n \big(\frac{n}{n+1}\big)^n.$$

Since $\big(\frac{n}{n+1}\big)^n < 1$, then $x_{n+1} < x_n$.

**Lemma 2:** $x_n$ is bounded.

*Proof*. Straightforward to see that $n! \leq n^n$ and $n! \geq 0$. We obtain the bounds $0 \leq x_n \leq 1$, demonstrating that $x_n$ is bounded.

Together, these two lemmas along with the monotone convergence theorem proves that the sequence converges.

**Theorem**: $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

*Proof*. Since $x_n$ converges, then let $s = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$, where $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Recall the relation in Lemma 1:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n \big(\frac{n}{n+1}\big)^n = \frac{x_n}{(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n}.$$

Since $x_n \to s$, then so does $x_{n+1}$. Furthermore, a standard result is the limit $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n \to e$. With these results, we have $\frac{x_n}{(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n} \to \frac{s}{e}$ and consequently

$$s = \frac{s}{e} \implies s(1 - e^{-1}) = 0$$

Since $1 \neq e^{-1}$, then this statement is satisfied if and only if $s = 0$ and that concludes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

You can prove that
$$
n! < \left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)^n.
$$
Now observe that
$$
0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n} <\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n }{n^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\cdot\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}.
$$
We know that $1/2^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. If you know that $[(n+1)/n]^n\to e$ as $n\to\infty$, then you're done... the limit is zero!

Definitely not as nice as anon's solution, but a different approach nontheless.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$ then $u_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{(n+1)}}$. Now, $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{(n+1)}}\times \frac{n^n}{n!}\\ =\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=e^{-1}<1.$$ By ratio test for sequences the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0.$

Answer (score 0):

No , both are equal in terms of their order of growth, obviously in terms of values $n^n$ is greater.

$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3).........1.$

Here , $n$ multiplies by $n$ times

So, $n!= n^n -$ something ,

here definitely something is less than $n^n$.

And in a function generally we considers highest order function among others , so $n! = n^n$ in terms of order of growth.
It's simply like $f(n)= n^2+n+2 , g(n)= n^2 + 2$ , here both are qudartic as well as they have $n^2$ as highest order function , so they are equal in growth.

Comment: This is wrong. As other answers show, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$. It's not clear what your reasoning is for instead thinking $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=1$. If it's thinking a product of $n$ terms each of limit $1$ has limit $1$, note the number of terms $\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: using
$$\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n<n!<e\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n\tag{1}$$
is easy to obtain the estimation
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}<e\cdot \frac{1}{2^n}\to 0,$$

I write down proof for right hand side of $(1)$, as we are using it, and left can be obtain similarly.

Using classical inequality for arithmetic and geometric averages $\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n}\geqslant \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}$ on first step, we have
$$n!<\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=e\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}{e\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n}=\\
=e\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{e}<e\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$$