# Which has a higher order of growth, n! or n^n?

Tags: exponential-function, factorial

In our algorithms class, my professor insists that n! has a higher order of growth than n^n. This doesn't make sense to me, when I work through what each expression means.

```
n! = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 2 * 1
n^n = n * n * n * n * ... * n * n
```

Since `n` is, by definition, greater than `n -1` or `n-2`, shouldn't any n^n, which is the product of `n` number of `n`'s, be greater than n!, which is the product of an `n` number of integers less than `n`?

Comment: Your professor is basing his assertion on what? Does he have an explanation? That's what I would ask if I were in his class.

Comment: I asked once, and he referred to Stirlings approximation, which he simplified as something like `n^(1/2) * n^n`.

Comment: There's an $e^{-n}$ missing in that version of Stirling.

Comment: Ah. That would certainly inhibit the growth! Glad to know I'm not going insane.

Comment: Are you sure that he meant $n^n$ and not $n^k$ (_or_ $k^n$)?  It's true that $n!$ grows faster than both of the other two - faster than polynomial and faster than exponential - and I would presume, absent specific quotes to the contrary, that that's what was meant.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/whats-the-limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnnn) question that shows $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n1}{n^n} = 0$ so $n^n$ grows faster.

Comment: I found this [video](https://youtu.be/Nd0XDY-jVHs?list=PLDN4rrl48XKpZkf03iYFl-O29szjTrs_O&t=185) very helpful for understanding how get the right asymptotic notation for f(n)=n!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Higher order of growth" does not mean that $n!\lt n^n$ but the stronger property that 
$$n!/n^n\to0.$$
To prove that this property holds, note that $n\geqslant2k$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n/2$ and $n\geqslant k$ for every $n/2\lt k\leqslant n$, hence
$$
n^n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}n\geqslant\prod_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n/2}(2k)\cdot\prod_{n/2\lt k\leqslant n}k=2^{n/2}\cdot n!,
$$
which proves that 
$$
\frac{n!}{n^n}\leqslant\frac1{2^{n/2}}\to0.
$$
Thus, indeed $n^n$ has a higher order of growth than $n!$, not the opposite.

Comment: Although `n^n > n!` does not prove that `n!/n^n -> 0` BUT it does prove that `n^n/n! -/> 0`. That is, it doesn't prove that it's a higher order of growth, but it proves that it's order of growth is at least as high. This is contrary to his professors claims.

Answer (score 7):

You are right that $n^n$ grows faster than $n!$. You can see [this question with answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/whats-the-limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnnn) (thanks to @JohnHabert for his comment above) for a proof which says exactly what you are saying. This is **illustrated** by just considering the first couple of numbers
$$
\begin{align}
1^1 = 1 \quad &\quad\quad 1! = 1\\
2^2 = 4 \quad &\quad\quad 2! = 2\\
3^3 = 27 \quad &\quad\quad 3! = 6\\
4^4 = 256 \quad &\quad\quad 4! = 24 \\
5^5 = 3125 \quad &\quad\quad 5! = 120 \\
\end{align}
$$
(Your professor might just have misspoken. I would go ask him for clarification.)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because the explanation is wrong.

Comment: This is definitely not a proof, not even very convincing: there are quite a huge number of sequences growing very slowly for the first $K$ terms, and yet very fast afterwards...

Comment: He didn't mispeak. He literally just corrected a student, and expanded on it in a previous lecture. He's a smart guy, I'm going to assume its a simple mixup.

Comment: @ClementC.: I did not claim to provide a proof. The OP did that!

Comment: @PLKTU: What is the "correct explanation" then? I don't see you trying to provide one.

Comment: @ClementC.: It seems like the other answer agree with me... ?

Comment: I did not say the answer was wrong — I merely said that th evidence you give is not a proof (on which you agree) not even evidence at all — since it can be discarded easily by other examples of sequence with the same first terms. Phrased differently, my point is that your answer is not bringing much insight.

Comment: @ClementC.: If you read the OP's question you see that the OP provides justification for why $n^n$ grows faster than $n!$. His question is simply whether or not he is correct in his thinking. My answer addresses exactly that. If he wanted a proof, I then even provide a link to a proof. Also, while examples in general don't prove anything, they can still **illustrate**.

Answer (score 3):

If $n\in \mathbb{N}$, Then $n! = 1 \times 2 \times 3\times 4...............\times (n-2)\times (n-1)\times n$

Now $n\geq n$ and $n>(n-1)$ and $n>(n-2)$ and $n>(n-3)$......... $n>4\;\;,n>3\;\;,n>2\;\;,n>1$

So $n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot ............\cdot n(n-\bf{times})\geq n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)....3\cdot 2 \cdot 1$

So $n^n\geq n!$

Comment: This is definitely the right idea.  The two functions are equal for $n=1$ and $n!$ never catches up afterwards.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, just like the sequences $n-(n-1)/2^n$ and $n$, and yet...

Comment: @Did Ok, so I am incorrectly taking "Higher order of growth" = "Higher rate of growth"

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is wrong, and the explanation can be found [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/growth.pdf) on page 5.