# Which grows at a faster rate $\ln(n!)$ or $\ln(n^n)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Which grows at a faster rate, $\ln(n!)$ vs $\ln(n^n)$? How to solve such type of questions considering $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: *Hint:* [$\ln(n!) = n\ln(n)-n+O(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Although $n^n\gg n!$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n!}{\ln n^n}=1$.

Comment: @Komono Chen Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674002/which-has-a-higher-order-of-growth-n-or-nn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\ln n^n = n\ln n = \ln n + \ln n + \cdots + \ln n> \ln 1 + \ln 2 + \ln 3 + \cdots + \ln n = \ln n!  $

Comment: Wow, that's clever

Comment: Thanks! But is this applicable even when $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @VisheshSharma Yes in the sense that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\ln(n^n) - \ln(n!)]= \infty$. No in the sense that $\lim_{n_\rightarrow\infty}[\ln(n^n)/\ln(n!)] = 1$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog How did you get $lim_{n→∞}[ln(n^n)/ln(n!)]=1$?

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) says $\ln n! = n\ln n - n + O(\ln n)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you.