# Help with Limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2 n)! (n)^n}{n! (2 n)^{2 n}}$

Tags: limits, factorial

Honestly, I am just plain stuck, I have been hitting my head against it for $2$ days straight. I know the solution should be $2^{-2}$ but...

Help would be appreciated. If anyone has a Wolfram Alpha PRO account I am sure that thing churns out the solution as it is something quite basic I just don't see it and its driving me crazy.

Edit: Stacks seemed to correct my formating from this sloppy one "Limit[(2 n)! n^n (E^n/(n! (2 n)^(2 n))), n -> Infinity]" $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2 n)! e^n (n)^n}{n! (2 n)^{2 n}}$

to this one $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2 n)! (n)^n}{n! (2 n)^{2 n}}$ somewhere dropping the $e^n$ term. I should have learned to propperly use latex in stackexchange first.

Comment: Please check that I have edited your question correctly. Also, please post whatever you have done (and has prompted headbanging), because we can point out mistakes and also whatever you have done correctly, and maybe carry on from where you have left off.

Comment: It might be worth looking at Stirling's approximation in an effort to simplify the limit.

Comment: Stirling's works, but it's a lot of overkill.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You were right, i used wrong formating that dropped the $e^n$ term after your edit. Won't happen again now that i know how formating here works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I see a problem of limits with factorials, I immediately think about [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left(p\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

$$A_n=\frac{(2 n)! (n)^n}{n! (2 n)^{2 n}}\implies \log(A_n)\sim\log((2n)!)+n\log(n)-\log(n!)-2n\log(2n)$$ Applying the formula and simplifying leads to $$\log(A_n)\sim \frac{\log (2)}{2}-n$$ from which you can easily conclude.

Comment: Made a mistake in my formatting there but ya i still see how this helps. Thanks

Comment: @KatptonLiamfuppinshire. Then, you just need to add $n$ to $\log(A_n)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$(2n-1)!!=1\cdot3\cdot 5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1) $$

$$\dfrac{(2n)!n^n}{n!(2n)^{2n}}=\dfrac{(2n-1)!!\cdot(2^nn!)\cdot n^n}{2^{2n} n^{2n} n!}=\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{2^{n} n^{n}}\le\dfrac{2^n\cdot n!}{2^n n^n}=\dfrac{n!}{n^n}$$Now since [$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n!}{n^n}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61741/170039) we have, $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{(2n)!n^n}{n!(2n)^{2n}}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{2n}!\, n^{n} \over n!\,\pars{2 n}^{2n}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\bracks{\root{2\pi}\pars{2n}^{2n + 1/2}\expo{-2n}}n^{n} \over \bracks{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}}\pars{2 n}^{2n}}\quad
\pars{~\begin{array}{l}
\mbox{by using}
\\
Stirling\ Asymptotic\ Expansion\end{array}~}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{2n}^{1/2}\expo{-n} \over n^{1/2}} =
\root{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\expo{-n} = \bbx{\ds{0}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{(2n)!\,n^n}{n!\,(2n)^{2n}}$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\log(a_n)&=\log((2n)!)+n\log(n)-\log(n!)-2n\log(2n)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\log(k/n)-2n\log(2)\\\\
&= \log(2)+\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\log(k/n)-2n\log(2)\\\\
&\le \log(2)+\int_n^{2n}\log(x/n)\,dx-2n\log(2)\\\\
&=\log(2)-n\\\\
\end{align}$$

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}\log(a_n)=-\infty$, then the limit of interest is

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\log(a_n)}=0$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (2n)! n^n }{n! (2n)^{2n}} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ 2n\cdot(2n-1) \cdots (n+1) \cdot n! \cdot  n^n }{n! 2^{2n} n^{2n}}\\
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ 2n\cdot(2n-1) \cdots (n+1)  }{ 2^{2n} n^{n}}
\end{align*}
This is the limit after a little bit of simplification. What can we say about the product on the top?

**Edit**

At least if I'm reading your problem correctly (there have been a few differing edits made to it) the limit should actually end up being $0$ (per Mathematica).

Answer (score 0):

As @erfink points out, the limit can be trivially rearranged to get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ 2n\cdot(2n-1) \cdots (n+1)  }{ 2^{2n} n^{n}}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ 2n\cdot(2n-1) \cdots (n+1)  }{(4n)^n}$$ 
From here I will show an intuitive understanding of how to complete the argument.
$$2n\cdot(2n-1) \cdots (n+1)$$
$$=(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)$$ 
And so we see that there are $n$ terms in the numerator, as in the denominator. Thus, if we convert the limit to to a product of limits we get
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n+1}{4n}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n+2}{4n}\cdots\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n+n}{4n}$$
Clearly all limits will be finite, and in fact all of the multiplied terms will all be less than $1$. Since there are infinitely many this must tend to zero (I leave this proof to the OP to formalize!)

**Note:** @dvix notes in the comments that the above can be seen a bit more rigorously if we note that each factor $\frac{n+k}{4n}\leq\frac 12$ for all $1\leq k \leq n$, so the product is $\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$. This is a tighter argument as it gives a bound for a given $n$ as opposed to my simpler "infinite terms less than $1$ (and greater than zero) equal $0$". Clearly $\frac{1}{2^n}$ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity

Comment: `Clearly all limits will be finite` But there is infinitely many of them.

Comment: @dxiv yes, I realized that this was not sufficient. I'm completing it right now with as elementary of an explanation as I can

Comment: @dxiv I instead was a bit more explicit with my thought process. There is of course still a little issue in that the number of multiplied limits increases as $n$ increases, which is only somewhat expressed by my notation. If you have any suggestions or corrections to make, please do. Excluding product notation I'm unsure of a notation to express this succinctly.

Comment: At this point, I think it's enough to point that each factor $\frac{n+k}{4 n} \le \frac{1}{2}$ for $1 \le k \le n$, so the product is $\le \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: @dxiv good point. That is definitely a little more formal (and arguably correct) than what I wrote. I'll include it as a note at the end. Thank you!