# Does $\sum \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ converge or diverge.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have plugged the sum into mathematica and know that the sum diverges but I cannot prove it. When I tried the root test I was able to simplify it to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}e}$ which I also had to plug into mathematica and got 1 which means the test is inconclusive. The same issue arose when I tried the root test. The only thing left that I can think to do is the comparison test which would require finding something smaller than $\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ that diverges but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Have you heard about [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)?

Comment: I had not but it seems to be smaller than n! so even though $\sum \frac{n^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^ne^n}=\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ diverges it still can't be used in the comparison test. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was wrong, I am apparently a bit distracted at the moment. Use the comparison test with the series $\sum \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi n}}$, the terms of which quickly become smaller than your series.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713) is related.

Comment: $\sum \frac2{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ is eventually significantly greater than $\sum \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ therefore when I say that $\sum \frac2{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ diverges I am not entitled to say that $\sum \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ also diverges. What comparison am I to make?

Comment: Ah that makes more sense thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lemma**: $\left\{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a decreasing sequence converging to $e$.

**Consequence**: since we have $n=\prod_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)$ for any $n\geq 2$,
$$ n! = \frac{n^{n}}{\prod_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}=\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{\prod_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k+1/2}}\leq\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{e^{n-1}} $$
and:
$$ \frac{n^n}{n! e^n} \geq \frac{1}{e\sqrt{n}} $$
trivially implying that $\sum_\limits{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n! e^n}$ is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}\div\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n}=\infty\;$ (as shown below) and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges,

the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ diverges by the Limit Comparison Test.

---

Since $f(x)=\ln x$ is concave down, the Trapezoidal rule estimate gives that

$\displaystyle\int_1^n\ln x \,dx>\ln n!-\frac{1}{2}\ln n,\;$ so $\;\displaystyle\ln n!<n\ln n-n+1+\frac{1}{2}\ln n$ and therefore

$\displaystyle\ln\left(\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n}\right)=(n+1)\ln n-\ln n!-n>(n+1)\ln n-[n\ln n-n+1+\frac{1}{2}\ln n]-n=\frac{1}{2}\ln n-1$.

Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n}\right)=\infty,\;$so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n}=\infty$.