# Does the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}·\left(\frac1e\right)^n$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis

I tried using the Stirling's formula since 
$$
\frac{n^n}{n!}·\left(\frac1e\right)^n < \frac{n^{(n+0.5)}}{n!}·e^n
$$
 which equals to $(1/2\pi)$

I think this series converges but can't prove it...

Comment: Try to use the Stirling formula the other way. Is any term of your series bigger than $\frac{1}{n}$ ?

Comment: Your insertion of Stirlings formula in your term seems faulty to a large degree.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059754/

Answer (score 2):

You have 
$$u_n = \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \frac{1}{n!} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}$$

according to Stirling formula which states
$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$$

Hence the series diverges as $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

By Stirling's approximation, you have

$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

Thus:

$$\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}\sim\frac{n^n e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}e^n n^n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$

The series you are considering is asymptotic to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
which is a $p$-series with $p = \frac{1}{2}\leq 1$ and is thus divergent. Therefore, your series diverges as well.