# Solving $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1)(2)(3)\cdots (n)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(2n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to solve this limit : 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1)(2)(3)\cdots (n)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(2n)}.$$
Any direction ? I think i should i use the Sandwich theorem or something else.

Comment: This ratio can be expressed as $\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}$, i.e., the reciprocal of the $n$th central binomial coefficient. But such coefficients grow without bound as $n$ increases, so...(This is not a rigorous proof, merely a heuristic.)

Comment: Hint: If $i \leq n$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{i}{n+i} \leq \frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit the limit is 0 ?

Comment: Yes ... as Semiclassical suggests too!

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit so if i need to use the Sandwich theorem i can say that :    -$-1/n<(1)(2)(3)⋯(n)(n+1)/(n+2)(n+3)⋯(2n)< 1/(n+1)$ ?

Comment: Yes ... use the lower bound $0 \leq$ and the upper bound $ \leq (1/2)^n$ ... Sandwich it to zero.

Comment: why the upper bound $(1/2)^n$ and not $1/(n+1)$ ? also the limit of  $1/(n+1)$ equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a silly proof: Let $a_n=\dfrac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$. Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} 
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{((n+1)!)^2}{(2n+2)!}\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{4}$$ which has magnitude less than $1$. Hence the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges by the ratio test. But such a series only converges if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots2n\ge n^n$$
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots2n}\le \frac{1}{n^n}$$
$$0\le\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n }{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots 2n}\le \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

If you are not familiar with $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$ this isn't very helpful.

Comment: i am not familiar with this , can i say that :               0<my product< $1/(n+1)$ ? i know that the limit of $1/(n+1)$ is 0 also..

Comment: @Majd i recommend getting familiar with it , it is useful and common https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61713/503397