# What is the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{n^{2}}}{(2n)!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{n^{2}}}{(2n)!}$.

I used the ratio test to calculate this limit, and I got here:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{2n}}{n^2}\frac{e}{4+6/n+2/n^2}$.

For the first fraction, I applied the ratio test again and got +inf.

I also attach pictures with a more detailed solution. I would like to ask if the procedure and result are correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The limit [graphically](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wjfoefmbyt) goes to infinity. Also, the writing is hard to see, so please try to [use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I have read through your solution, and it seems fine! You might have heard of the phrase "The exponential $x\mapsto e^x$ grows faster than any polynomial in $x$ for $x\to \infty$". This is another manifestation of this fact.

Comment: Your calculations look fine, but you should explain how they answer the question. Specifically, your last step says that a particular limit diverges to $\infty$, but that particular limit is not the limit you were asked to evaluate...

Comment: You get the same result if you take the natural log of the initial function then take the limit. $\approx x^2-x\ln{x}$ approaches infinity.

Comment: @Stardust9922 I was confused by the factorial, because it generally grows the fastest.

Comment: Ratio test doesn't make sense, you are taking a limit not computing the convergence of a series right?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Although you're right that the ratio test is used for series and not limits, there is a similar argument you can make where if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is finite, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x + 1)}{f(x)} = 1.$ Here that limit doesn't go to $1$ so the limit cannot be finite. I'm not sure if the OP knows this but the argument actually does work out

Comment: I would try to use Stirling's approximation, and then take logarithm of the original expression and let $\ n\to\infty,\ $ giving us that the logarithm of the original expression $\ \to\infty\ $ as $\ n\to\infty,\ $and then suggest that this implies the original limit $\ \to\infty\ $ as $\ n\to\infty.\ $ But I'm not sure how sound this method is.

Comment: A hint for doing this by examining factors: $\frac{e^{4^2}}{8!}=\frac{1}{1}\frac{e}{2}\frac{e^2}{3}\frac{e^2}{4}\frac{e^2}{5}\frac{e^2}{6}\frac{e^2}{7}\frac{e^3}{8}\cdot e^2>e^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps it becomes clearer that the limit is infinite, making the series expansion of the exponential

$$   \dfrac{e^{n^2}}{(2n)!} = \dfrac{\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n^2)^m}{m!} }{(2n)!} \geq  \dfrac{n^{4n}}{  
 ( (2n)!)^2 }=   \left(  \dfrac{n^{2n}}{  
  (2n)! } \right)^2 $$
the last expression on the right is $\geq Cn$ ($C>0$) for large n.

Comment: "the last expression on the right is $\geq Cn$ ($C>0$) for large n." Why?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/whats-the-limit-of-the-sequence-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracnnn

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write $\displaystyle \frac{e^{n^2}}{(2n)!}$ as

$$\frac{e^{n^2}}{(2n)!}=e^{n\left(n-\frac1n\log((2n)!)\right)}$$

Now, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n-\frac1n\log((2n)!)\right)>0$ (in fact, the limit is $\infty$).

---

---

**HINT $2$:**

Use the fact that

$$\begin{align}
\frac1n\log((2n)!&=2\log(2n)+\frac2{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\log(k/2n)\\\\
&=2\log(2n)-2 +o(1)\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to\infty
\end{align}$$

Can you proceed now?

Answer (score 1):

By Stirling's approximation
$$\frac{e^{n^{2}}}{(2n)!} \sim \frac{e^{n^2} e^{2n}}{\sqrt{4\pi n} (2n)^{2n}} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi }} \exp \left(n^2 + 2n - 2n \log(2n) - \frac{1}{2}\log(n) \right) \longrightarrow +\infty$$

as $n \rightarrow +\infty$.