# Does the series $\sum n!/n^n$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus

so I used the root test, but i'm not quite sure if i'm allowed to. I think im performing the operations correctly,a and i keep ending up with $(1)^{\infty}$. So really my question is am i performing the operations wrong or do i have to use a different test?

Comment: By Stirling approximation, $n!/n^n \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} e^{-n}$. So by limit comparison test, $\sum n!/n^n$ converges.

Comment: yes, it converges to http://oeis.org/A094082

Comment: @tetori we haven't learned about anything called the stirling approximation in class

Comment: @lawlipop essentially in the limit the ratio of $n!/n^n$ to $\sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-n}$ tends towards $1$, and since we're interested in asymptotic behavior...

Comment: Duplicate of [Is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$ convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81113/is-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracnnn-convergent)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ldots$$

And yes: it converges.

Comment: Why the "-" before the 1/...?

Comment: @DonAntonio yea i too was wondering about the negative?

Comment: Notice the ratio of successive terms converges to $1/e$.

Comment: That minus after the equality sign must have been an act of god: I've no idea how it got there...well, I do have an idea but putting the blame on god makes me feel better. Thanks.

Comment: The limit of the above is $\frac 1e \approx 0.36788$, which is the same thing I got in a more roundabout way. But why does WolframAlpha report the answer is 1.87985 (see: http://tinyurl.com/n99hwld)

Comment: @Jeff Because one thing is the limit of the **sequence** in the above answer, and way another is the *sum* of the **series** the question asks about...

Comment: Why does this converge to $\frac{1}{e}$? Where does the $e$ come from?

Answer (score 19):

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdot\frac{3}{n}\cdot ... \cdot \frac{n}{n}\leq 
\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdot1\cdot ... \cdot 1= \frac{2}{n^2}$$

Comment: @HalilDuru ty fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a completely elementary proof
with an explicit upper bound of 4:

$n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i$,
so, reversing the order of the terms,
$n! = \prod_{i=1}^n (n+1-i)$.

Multiplying these,
$n!^2 = \prod_{i=1}^n i(n+1-i)$.
But

$\begin{align}
i(n+1-i) = i(n+1) - i^2
&= \frac{(n+1)^2}{4} - \frac{(n+1)^2}{4} +i(n+1) - i^2\\
&= \frac{(n+1)^2}{4} - (i-\frac{n+1}{2})^2\\
&\le \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}
\end{align}
$

so

$\begin{align}
n!^2 &\le \prod_{i=1}^n {(n+1)^2}{4}\\
&= \big(\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\big)^n\\
&= \big(\frac{n+1}{2}\big)^{2n}\\
\end{align}
$

or
$n! \le \big(\frac{n+1}{2}\big)^{n}$,
so
$$\frac{n!}{n^n} \le \big(\frac{n+1}{2n}\big)^n
= \big(\frac1{2}+\frac1{2n}\big)^n$$

Since $\frac1{2}+\frac1{2n} \le \frac{3}{4}$ for $n \ge 2$,

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{n!}{n^n} 
&\le 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^n\\
&=1 + \frac{(3/4)^2}{1-3/4}\\
 &= 1 + 9/4\\
 &= 13/4\\
 &< 4\\
\end{align}
$.

Comment: I think this is an interesting answer but you should use \frac{a}{b} (between dollar signs, of course) to express a fraction instead of a/b, and also use double line space and double dollar sign to center and make things bigger and clear, for example compare: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n!/n^n\,$ with $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{n^n}$$ The first one is with one sign dollar to both sides, the ends one with &two& signs dollars at each side...As it is chances are that many people just don't took the time to try to read your answer because it looks messy.

Comment: I know about those commands, but just was too lazy. However, when I did the reformatting as you suggested, I got two upvotes! Thanks. II will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is that $n! \approx c \sqrt{n}(n/e)^n$
for some real $c$.

Then $n!/n^n \approx c \sqrt{n}/e^n$
so the sum converges.

Actually, this shows that
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n n!/n^n$
converges for $|x| < e$.

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit? Where does $n! \approx c \sqrt{n}(n/e)^n$ come from?

Comment: It comes from Sterling's approximation - you can look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Use d'Alembert's ratio test, it's not hard to find the convergence of the series. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test