# Does this series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I showed that, by a combination of the root test and Stirling's approximation, the series $$\sum \frac{n^n}{n!}$$ converges (the ratio test is inconclusive.)  However a solution that I am comparing my work to claims the series diverges.

Who is right?

Thanks,

Comment: The terms are all $\ge 1$.

Comment: Oh geez, ok thanks @brianm.scott, I will try again ...

Comment: The series diverges.  $n^n\ge n!$ for $n\ge 1$.  Did you mean $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n!}{n^n}$?  That series converges.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354487/does-the-series-sum-n-nn-converge-or-diverge) for a similar question and hint

Comment: Hi @dr.mv nope I didn't mean the series you're suggesting.  Where's my fault in logic?  Using the root test and stirling's approx conveniently left me with $e/\sqrt{2\pi n}$ which goes to zero, and I get convergence by the root test.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: How does that go to zero ?

Comment: Sorry @shailesh I edited my typo ..

Comment: I found my mistake @dr.mv - thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @shailesh the limit is actually e, which is greater than 1.  Thanks :-)

Comment: ... which means the series ..... which is what Brian Scott observed in the first comment very succinctly. So as a learning process, may be you should just put together everything and post it as an answer. I'll definitely upvote that.

Comment: Hi @shailesh, unfortunately I am on pen, paper and phone - so I would like to limit my typing during the holiday over the next few days, until I get computer access again.  I'll try my best to, though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This series does indeed diverge. One way to see this is that, for all $n>1$ we know that
$$n^n>n!$$
This is obvious to see because $n^n$ is the product of $n$ terms that are equal to $n$ while $n!$ is the product of $n$ terms that are $\le n$. Because of this, this series is essentially adding infinite terms that are $\ge 1$, which obviously diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Very nice intuitive answer - earlier I proved this fact using induction, which wasn't hard.  But now I see that there's an even easier observation from your approach.  Thanks so much @WillFischer :-)