# convergent series for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus

Help me please , I am not able to solve this problem.I have tried in many ways to figure out such as Ration test , Integral test , Comparison test , Limit Comparison Test , Root Test but i can't find the way out . This is my first question and i'm not good at English. If there is something wrong or you are not comfortable with my language usage I'm so sorry.

Comment: You may find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354487/does-the-series-sum-n-nn-converge-or-diverge helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to factorial-based problems is to use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}n^ne^{-n}$, which shows this series converges provided $\sum_{n\ge 1}\sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-n}$ does, which is the case. If you didn't know this result, another option is to note that $$\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}\approx\frac{1}{e},$$completing the problem by the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the fraction as

$$\frac1n\frac2n\frac3n\cdots\frac nn,$$

you see that half of the factors are below $\dfrac12$ and the rest below $1$, and you can bound the general term by $\dfrac1{2^{n/2}}$.