# How can I find the convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n! \over n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Using either root test or ratio test. I have the feeling that it is the root test, I'm not sure how to proceed from this:

$$ \sqrt[n]{n! \over n^n}= {(n!)^{1\over n} \over n} $$

Comment: If the terms involve factorial, always try the ratio test first. Root test is good for those cases where the terms are like $n^n, n^{n^2}$ etc or their combination.

Comment: This question, again. Will find duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the limit of $\frac {n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn)

Comment: We have the following identity: $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n!}{n^n} ~=~ \int_0^\infty\frac{E(x)}{e^x}~dx,\quad$ where $\quad E(x)~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^n}\quad$ and $e^x~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}~,\quad$ and $\quad\displaystyle\lim_{n\to0}n^n~=~1$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$ convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81113/is-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracnnn-convergent)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ratio test. Here is a start

> $$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{(1+1/n)^n}\longrightarrow_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{e} <1 $$

Comment: so $a_{n+1}\text{~}\dfrac{a_n}{e}$ - can we use $1+1/e+1/e^2+1/e^3+\dots$ somewhere

Comment: now can we do the same with the pesky root test...

Answer (score 1):

Also $\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1}{n\cdot n \cdots n} \le \frac{2\cdot 1}{n\cdot n} = \frac{2}{n^2}$ for large $n,$ if that helps