# Show that $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}/a_{n-k}\leq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}^{k/n}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Here is an exercise:
Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a positive increasing sequence, can we prove that:
$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-k}}\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}^{k/n}$? Could someone give me some hints?

Comment: Let $L = \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n-k}}$. If $L = 0$, you're done. If $L > 0$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $n_\varepsilon$ such that $$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-k}} > L-\varepsilon$$ for all $n \geqslant n_\varepsilon$.

Comment: The inequality $\liminf(a_{n+1}/a_n) \le \liminf((a_n)^{(1/n)})$ seems related, so looking at a proof of that one might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).