# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial, radicals

Im tempted to say that the limit of this sequence is 1 because infinite root of infinite number is close to 1 but maybe Im mising here something? What will be inside the root?
This is the sequence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}}$$

Comment: Your argument that an infinite root of an infinite number is 1 is unsound: in fact, $\infty^0$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: Can we downvote comments?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that
$$1\ge\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}=\frac{3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-2)}\cdot\frac1{2n}\ge\frac1{2n}$$
So the limit is $1$ by squeezing as $\sqrt[n]n\to1.$

Comment: @robjohn Hopefully the answer is clear to everyone now.

Comment: @user2345215  How is the limit as $n\to\infty 1/(2n) = 1$?

Comment: @user2345215, that's great +1 well deserved!

Comment: @Amad27: it is not that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2n}=1$, but rather $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{2n}\right)^{1/n}=1$

Comment: @robjohn, that's what I meant, it was a typo, thanks !

Comment: @Amad27 That's a well known limit asked here many many times. One method is $n^{\frac1n}=e^{\frac{\ln n}n}$ and $\frac{\ln n}n\to 0$ is another well known limit, so $\sqrt[n]n=n^{\frac1n}\to e^0=1$

Comment: @user2345215 How did you take the $1 \over 2n$ outside?

Comment: @kfir124 I took it from the denominator, numerator stays the same.

Comment: @user2345215 Oh its -2 instead of -1 because the jumps are jumps of two right? and you proved that the limit of the inner expression(inside the root) is 1 so we say that doing n root over something that has a limit of 1 is 1 too when n goes to ininfite?

Comment: @kfir124 Yes to the first question. No to the second, the limit of the inner expression is unknown from this, as $\frac1{2n}$ goes to $0$, I'm squeezing the original limit with the root because when you take the root, suddenly $\sqrt[n]{\frac1{2n}}$ goes to $1$ and it's fine.

Comment: Yea my bad I overlooked because the left side 1 confused me a bit. clean and nice solution thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain how you got the half (1/2) out of the limit?

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$
\left[\frac1{2n+1}\right]^{1/n}=\left[\frac13\frac35\frac57\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\right]^{1/n}\le\left[\frac12\frac34\frac56\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right]^{1/n}\lt1
$$
Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(2n+1)^{1/n}=1$, the Squeeze Theorem says that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac12\frac34\frac56\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right]^{1/n}=1
$$

---

**Addendum**

Since $1+x\le e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we easily have
$$
(1+\sqrt{n}/2)^2\le \left(e^{\sqrt{n}/2}\right)^2
$$
which implies that
$$
1+2n\le8e^{\sqrt{n}}
$$
Therefore
$$
1\le(1+2n)^{1/n}\le8^{1/n}e^{1/\sqrt{n}}
$$
By the Squeeze Theorem,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n+1)^{1/n}=1
$$

Answer (score 3):

If you insert the denominator into the numerator you have $$\frac{1\times 3\times 5\cdots \times(2n-1)}{2\times 4\times 6\cdots \times(2n)}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$$ Now, use Stirling approximation $$m!=m^m \sqrt{2\pi m}e^{-m}$$

Comment: @Michael. I just noticed ! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy to show by induction that:
$$\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\tag{1}$$
since the last line is implied by:
$$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\geq\sqrt{\frac{2n}{2n+2}}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$(2n+1)^2\geq 2n(2n+2) = (2n+1)^2-1.$$
Using $(1)$ and the trivial bound $\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\leq 1$, it follows that the limit is $1$ by squeezing.

Answer (score 2):

You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots2n} &=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4 \cdot 5\cdot6\cdots(2n-1)\cdot 2n}{(2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n))^2}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^{n} \cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots n)^2}\\
& =\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2 }\\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right), \quad \text{for} \, n \, \text{great}
\end{align}
$$
where we have use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), then you easily conclude, since
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots2n}}=e^{\Large \frac{1}{n}\log{\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots2n}}}
$$
giving the value $1$ for your limit.

Answer (score 2):

Taking log and Cesaro-Stolz:
$$\eqalign{\log L &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\log(1)+\log(3)+\ldots+\log(2n-1))-(\log(2)+\log(4)+\ldots+\log(2n))}n=\cr
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(2n+1)-\log(2n+2)}1=0.}$$

Answer (score 1):

A recent question here showed that the expression inside the root was roughly $\sqrt{1/n}$.  The $n$th root of that approaches 1.
$$\log f(n)=\frac1n\left(\log\frac12+\log\frac34+...+\log\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)\\ 
\approx\frac1n\left(C_1-\frac12-\frac14\cdots-\frac1{2n}\right)\\
\approx\frac1n\left(C_2-\log n\right)/2\\
\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Multiply numerator and denominator by $(2 \cdot 4 \cdots 2n)$ and remember that $2 \cdot 4 \cdots 2n = 2^n \cdot n!$

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply top and bottom by $2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots 2n$ and simplify, you should get an expression $\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}}$, which can be approximated using Stirling's formula.

Comment: Same time + same words ! Are you my young twin brother ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I know, right? It took me about 20 seconds to write that answer, and when I click "post", there are three almost identical answers to mine!

Comment: At least, this shows that the community is ... a community !!

Answer (score 1):

Using the following inequality 
\begin{equation}
\frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2k}} } \leq \sqrt[n]{(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{4})...(1-\frac{1}{2n})} \leq \frac{(1-\frac{1}{2})+(1-\frac{1}{4})+...,(1-\frac{1}{2n})}{n} = 1-\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}
\end{equation}
and another results
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = \ln(n) + \gamma ,n \rightarrow \infty,
\end{equation}
where $\gamma $ is Euler constant. 
and 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1 +1}{2k-1} = n + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}\leq n + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} 
\end{equation}

Hence we have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{n}{n+\ln(n) + \gamma} \leq \sqrt[n]{(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{4})...(1-\frac{1}{2n})} \leq 1 - \frac{\ln(n) + \gamma}{2n} 
\end{equation}

Comment: @askyne from where is result in second step from?

Comment: And i revise my answer again,thank you for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a _n=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}.$$
Note that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\to1
$$
as $n\to \infty$. By this MSE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf) which proves that, 
$$
\liminf(b_{n+1}/b_n) \leq \liminf(b_n^{1/n}) \leq \limsup(b_n^{1/n}) \leq \limsup(b_{n+1}/b_n)
$$
for any sequence $(b_n)$ such that $b_n>0$, it follows that
$$
a_n^{1/n}\to1
$$
as $n\to\infty$.