# To show for following sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ where $a_n$ = $1.3.5 ... (2n-1)\over 2.4.6...(2n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, infinite-product

How can I show

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$

$a_n = {1.3.5 ... (2n-1)\over 2.4.6...(2n)}$

I have shown that $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing. I thought to shown sequence is bounded from below then it automatically would converge and hence my question will be solve. But I'm unable to show its boundedness... Or there maybe another method to prove this. Thanks

Comment: Clarification request: what do you mean by $1.3.5...$? Are these numbers being added?

Comment: I think is multiplication of odd numbers. Isn't $\pi$ in the answer? I vaguely remember a result like this from Euler.

Comment: It is certainly bounded below, since all terms are positive, so it converges. But that does not show it converges to $0$. The Stirling approximation will show convergence to $0$, but one can do it with less machinery.

Comment: Try to prove using induction that:$$a_n\lt\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$$

Comment: That the limit is zero is intuitively obvious, seeing as $a_n=\binom{2n}n/4^n$is the probability of getting exactly $n$ heads in $2n$ independent tosses of a fair coin.

Comment: @user121270 Can u pls justify ur comment . Why have u choosen that specific thing ?

Comment: @mapierce271 imean by 1.3.5 is numbers are being multiplied

Comment: @AndréNicolas I havent studies stirlings approximation . If u know this by other means pls let me know

Comment: This limit is somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024290/how-to-evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-frac1-cdot3-cdot5-cdot-ldots-cdot2

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks!!

Comment: This question is very close to the OP: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584456/limit-of-a-fraction-of-double-factorials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply the numerator by the denominator; so $$a_n=\frac{1\times3\times5\times ... \times(2n-1)}{ 2\times4\times6\times...\times(2n)}=\frac{1\times2\times3\times ... \times(2n)}{\Big(2\times4\times6\times...\times(2n)\Big)^2}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$$ If now you use Stirling approximation $$m! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi } e^{-m} m^{m+\frac{1}{2}}$$ and then $$a_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n} }$$ A more detailed approach would show for the asymptotic behavior $$a_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n} }\Big(1-\frac{1}{8n}\Big)$$

Comment: In first step how have u written in denominatorof last inequality as $4^{n}(n!)^{2}$ ..

Comment: Factor $2$ inside the brackets of denominator and square.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici in stirlings aproximstion  as you have mentioned in order to find formula for 2m! I just have to replace m by 2m in above formula .if i do this then im not getting to answer, thanks

Comment: @JessicaGtb. I don't know whee you had a problem since if you use Stirling, you should get $$(2n)! \approx \sqrt{\pi } 2^{2 m+1} e^{-2 m} m^{2 m+\frac{1}{2}}$$ Post if you still have problems. Cheers :-)

Comment: How did you get that expression for 2n! .it  is not same when you replace n by 2n in formula you mentioned in answer

Comment: It is the same (just expanded accordingly).

Answer (score 16):

$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$
$k^2+2k<k^2+2k+1\Rightarrow k(k+2)<(k+1)^2\Rightarrow\frac{k}{k+1}<\frac{k+1}{k+2}$

$\therefore a_n=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5...(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6...2n}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}...\frac{k}{k+1}...\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}...\frac{k+1}{k+2}...\frac{2n}{2n+1}=\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6...2n}{1\cdot3\cdot5...(2n+1)}$
where, $k$ is an odd natural number. 
$\Rightarrow {a_n}^2<\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5...(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6...2n}\cdot\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6...2n}{1\cdot3\cdot5...(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$

> $\Rightarrow 0<a_n<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Using Squeeze theorem, we get $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim} a_n=0$.

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but can you please tell me how did you infer $\therefore a_n=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5...(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6...2n}<\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6...2n}{1\cdot3\cdot5...(2n+1)}$ from 
$n(n+2)<(n+1)^2\Rightarrow\frac{n}{n+1}<\frac{n+1}{n+2}$? Thanks!!

Comment: @NatashaJ I hope you have understood how we get $\frac{k}{k+1}<\frac{k+1}{k+2}$. Now check that, for $n=1$ you get $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{2}{3}$, for  $n=3$ you get $\frac{3}{4}<\frac{4}{5}$, and so on. In other words for an odd $k$, you see that $\frac{k}{k+1}<\frac{k+1}{k+2}$.

Comment: @NatashaJ I have modified the step, hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: thanks so much. Now I get it!

Answer (score 8):

**Using $\boldsymbol{1+x\le e^x}$**

Since $1+x\le e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\\
&\le\prod_{k=1}^ne^{-\large\frac1{2k}}\\[3pt]
&=e^{-\frac12H_n}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where $H_n$ are the [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). Since the [Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverges, $(1)$ tends to $0$.

---

**Using [Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028)**
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k-\frac12}{k}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\sqrt\pi\,\Gamma(n+1)}\\[6pt]
&\le\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Commentary**

Gautschi's Inequality also says that
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\sqrt\pi\,\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&\ge\frac1{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac12\right)}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\,a_n=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\tag{4}
$$
Putting the second line of $(1)$ and the limit in $(4)$ together, we can show that
$$
\gamma+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\zeta(n)}{n2^{n-1}}=\log(\pi)\tag{5}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\zeta$ is the [Riemann Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Answer (score 5):

Let's prove using induction that $$a_n\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}.$$ For $n=1$ it is true. Now we just need to prove that$$\frac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n+2)^2}\le\frac{3n+1}{3n+4}$$or $$(4n^2+4n+1)(3n+4)\le(4n^2+8n+4)(3n+1)$$or$$12n^3+28n^2+19n+4\le12n^3+28n^2+20n+4.$$

Comment: If we are not given the limit it converges to then how would we go about it

Comment: I don't know. Maybe we could find asymtothics using Stirling's formula, then try to find this inequality.

Comment: (+1) It's neater with $n - 1$ in place of $n$:
$$
\left(\frac{2n - 1}{2n}\right)^2 \leqslant \frac{3n - 2}{3n + 1}
\iff \frac{4n - 1}{4n^2} \geqslant \frac3{3n + 1} \iff
(4n - 1)(3n + 1) \geqslant 12n^2 \iff n \geqslant 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence can be rewritten as
$$a_n=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot...\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot...\cdot2n}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot(2n-1)\cdot2n}{(2\cdot4\cdot...\cdot2n)^2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$
Using Stirling's approximation we get
$$a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\sim\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 2n}\cdot(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}}{(\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n)^2}=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot2^{2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: i havent studied stirlings approximation yet . Can u show me another way which uses sequence series concepts