# Compute limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1*3*5*...*(2n-1) }{ 2*4*6*...*(2n)}=0$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( \frac{1*3*5*...*(2n-1) }{ 2*4*6*...*(2n)}\right)^3=0$$
Having products at fractions I cant figure out how to calculate this limit.

Comment: I think this will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025630/to-show-for-following-sequence-lim-n-to-infty-a-n-0-where-a-n-1-3/1025669#1025669

Comment: Which limit do you want to compute? The one in the title or the one in the body of the question?

Comment: the one in the body

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a_n:=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)}
=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$

Then use the Stirling formula:
$$
n! \sim  \sqrt  {2\pi n} n^n e^{-n}
\\
a_n \sim
\frac{\sqrt  {4\pi n} (2n)^{2n} e^{-2n}}
{2^{2n} 2\pi n n^{2n} e^{-2n}} 
= \frac{\sqrt  {4\pi n} }
{2\pi n } \to 0
$$