# Convergence of sequences 3

Tags: sequences-and-series

These are two sequences we want to study convergent for it
I need a hint to determine whether the following sequences convergent or divergent.
 $$\mathcal X_n=\frac{1+2+3+...+n}{n^2}$$
For this I have already tried 
$$\mathcal  1+2+3+...+n =\frac {n(n+1)}{2}$$ so
$$\mathcal X_n=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$ hence$$ \mathcal X_n\to \frac{1}{2}$$.
 $$\mathcal Y_n =\frac{2.4.6...2n}{1.3.5...(2n-1)}$$
What should I use to solve it.

Comment: Is it convergent sequence

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion for $X_n$ looks fine. For $Y_n$, a similar question has been answered here: [To show for following sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ where $a_n$ = $1.3.5 ... (2n-1)\over 2.4.6...(2n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025630/to-show-for-following-sequence-lim-n-to-infty-a-n-0-where-a-n-1-3)