# Limit of given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the limit of sequence $a(n)$=
$\left(\frac{1.3.5....(2n-1)}{2.4.6....(2n)}\right)$.

I calculate $\lim \left(\frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}\right)$ which comes 1.So I am confirm that limit of $a(n)$$\ne$$0$.But what is actual limit?

Comment: It is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1025659/499203) very briefly.

Comment: All answers have used concept of stirling approximation which I haven't studied yet...any easy way..

Comment: Really all? Did you have a look at this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1025669/42969 ?

Comment: Not all..I also look at this but sorry didn't get this one too..

Answer (score 0):

Easy with *Bernoulli's inequality*: we'll prove the inverse tends to $+\infty$. Indeed
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}\right)&=
\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{1}\Bigr)\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{3}\Bigr)\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{5}\Bigr)\dotsm \Bigl(1+\frac{1}{2n-1}\Bigr) \\\
&\ge 1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dotsm +\frac{1}{2n-1},
\end{align}
and the latter tends to $+\infty$.