# Prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges, where $a_n$ = $\frac{1 · 3 · 5 · · ·(2n − 1)}{2 · 4 · 6 · · ·(2n)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges, where $a_n$ = $\frac{1 · 3 · 5 · · ·(2n − 1)}{2 · 4 · 6 · · ·(2n)}$. Use Monotonic Convergence Theorem.

Here is my proof:

> Since $a_n = \frac{2n-1}{2n}$, then $a_{n+1} = \frac{2n-1+1}{2n+1} = \frac{2n}{2n+1}$.
> Therefore, $a_n$ = $\frac{2n-1}{2n}\le\frac{2n}{2n+1}$ = $a_{n+1}$, and so the sequence, $a_n$, is increasing for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and is monotonic. The term $a_n$ has an upper bound (ie. 1) and a lower bound (ie. 0) for all $n$ and thus is bounded. Therefore, $a_n$ converges by the Monotonic Convergence Theorem.

Please check it over and make sure it sounds all right. If there is anything wrong, please let me know what and how I can fix it.

Comment: How do you get from $a_n = \frac{1 · 3 · 5 \cdots (2n − 1)}{2 · 4 · 6 \cdots(2n)}$ to  $a_n = \frac{2n-1}{2n}$?

Comment: While $\frac{2n-1}{2n}$ is an increasing sequence, its partial products are a decreasing sequence with lower limit $0$. Do you want to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists, or $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ exists?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1025630/42969 for a correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by noting that the sequence is decreasing. In fact,
$$
\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \dfrac{2n+1}{2n+2} < 1 \Rightarrow a_{n+1}< a_n.
$$

Also, the sequence is clearly bounded. Since it is decreasing and positive, we have that $0 < a_n \leq a_1$.

Finally, being monotonic and bounded, the sequence is convergent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to proofs. Can you explain how you got 2n+2 in the denominator?

Comment: $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \dfrac{\dfrac{1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)(2n+1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n)(2n+2)}}{\dfrac{1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n)}}$$

So, everuthing cancels out, except for $\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the dup solution, you can find a recursive relation for $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$. One has: $a_{n+1} = \dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n+1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n+2)}= \dfrac{2n+1}{2n+2}\cdot a_n< a_n$ since $2n+1 < 2n+2$. And $a_n > 0$ for all $n$, hence it converges as a monotonically decreasing and bounded below sequence.