# root testing a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I've seen an example that the root test is stronger than the ratio test [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Root_test), and tried to deal with it myself but it didn't go well;

Here's my attempt:

$
1\\
+1\\
+0.5+0.5\\
+0.25+0.25+0.25+0.25\\
+\dots\\
=4\\$

$
a_1 = a_2 = 1,\ a_n = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil-1}\ n\geq 3\\$

where $\lceil 3.5\rceil=4$ is the ceiling function

$
\text{root test : }\limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \limsup \sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil-1}}
=\limsup \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil-1}{n}}\\
\leq \limsup \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{\log_2 n-1}{n}}
=\limsup 2^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\log_2{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}}
= 1\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\log_2{\limsup n^{\frac{1}{n}}}}\\
=1\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\log_2 1}=1,
$

so it's inconclusive.

I guess I did a mistake when I found the general term $a_n$ or in the middle of the root test(after $\leq$).

I know this series is inconclusive when using the ratio test. So I just need to fix this root test thing, but I got stuck.

(And this is just a counterexample of (root test) $\subset$ (ratio test). How do we know that (root test) $\supset$ (ratio test)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shown that

$$\liminf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le \liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n}\le \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}\le \limsup\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

therefore convergence by ratio test implies convergence by root test but not viceversa.

Refer also to the related:

- [Theorem 3.37 in Baby Rudin: $\lim\inf\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\leq\lim\inf\sqrt[n]{c_n}\leq\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{c_n}\leq \lim\sup\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1764134/505767)

For the series we can use that

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil-1}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,\sum_{k=2^{n}+1}^{2^{n+1}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}
=\sum_{n=3}^\infty(2^{n}-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}$$

Comment: Thank you! And... could you teach me how to root test that specific series? It keeps bothers me :P

Comment: Are you forced to use root test? It seems indeed inconclusive but you don't need limsup to see that.

Comment: No, but in that article they presented it as an example and didn't show the trick; so I'm just curious.

Comment: @user159234 I've added an alternative way. Could you attach the article in your OP, I'm curious to see that.

Comment: I linked it at the top. thanks.

Comment: @user159234 The given series in the wiki page is not the one you have given here.

Comment: oh, you're right. my series diverges

Comment: @user159234 It should be $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$$