# If $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n)^{1/n}=L$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n>0 \space \forall \space n \in N$

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n)^{1/n}=L$

This theorem is given in my book without proof. It looks very strange to me. Any suggestion about how to prove or derive it?

Comment: Radius of convergence.

Comment: Think about Logarithm and Cesaro.

Comment: Your book should have proved it considering that such theorems are not meant for introductory calculus course (where avoiding proofs is routine). The proof is not difficult but you need to have some experience with $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of a limit to understand the proof.

Comment: [See this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178272/finding-limit-using-inequalities-liminf-fraca-n1a-n-le-liminf-a-n/2178670#2178670) for a more general result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof
from first principles.

If
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L
$,
then,
for any $c > 0$,
for all $n > n_0(c)$,
$L-c
\lt \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}
\lt L+c
$.

Therefore,
for any $N > n_0(c)$,
$(L-c)^{N-n_0(c)}
\lt \prod_{n=n_0(c)}^{N-1} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}
=\dfrac{x_N}{x_{n_0(c)}}
\lt (L+c)^{N-n_0(c)}
$
so that
$x_{n_0(c)}(L-c)^{N-n_0(c)}
\lt x_N
\lt x_{n_0(c)}(L+c)^{N-n_0(c)}
$
or
$x_{n_0(c)}\dfrac{(L-c)^{N}}{(L-c)^{n_0(c)}}
\lt x_N
\lt x_{n_0(c)}\dfrac{(L+c)^{N}}{(L+c)^{n_0(c)}}
$.

Taking the $N$th root,
and rearranging a little,
$(L-c)\left(\dfrac{x_{n_0(c)}}{(L-c)^{n_0(c)}}\right)^{1/N}
\lt x_N^{1/N}
\lt (L+c)\left(\dfrac{x_{n_0(c)}}{(L+c)^{n_0(c)}}\right)^{1/N}
$.

Both
$\dfrac{x_{n_0(c)}}{(L-c)^{n_0(c)}}$
and
$\dfrac{x_{n_0(c)}}{(L+c)^{n_0(c)}}$
are independent of $N$,
so
$\lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\dfrac{x_{n_0(c)}}{(L\pm c)^{n_0(c)}}\right)^{1/N}
=1
$.

Therefore,
for large enough $N$,
$1-c 
\lt \left(\dfrac{x_{n_0(c)}}{(L\pm c)^{n_0(c)}}\right)^{1/N}
\lt 1+c
$,
so that
$(L-c)(1-c)
\lt x_N^{1/N}
\lt (L+c)(1+c)
$.

Now let $c \to 0$
and,
for each $c$,
let $N$ be sufficiently large
and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L$. Then
$$\frac{1}{L}=\frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$$
by continuity of $\frac1x$ for $x>0$. We recognize $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$ as the radius of convergence for the power series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_nx^n$$ which we will denote $R$. Similarly, we know that the radius of convergence for the above series is given as $\frac1{\limsup_\limits{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_n}}$ since $x_n>0$. Notice that
$$\frac1L=R=\frac1{\limsup_\limits{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_n}}=\frac1{\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_n}}$$ in this case (due to our original assumption).

Answer (score 2):

If $x_n>0 ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $L>0$.

> If $a_{n+1}-a_n \to a \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\frac{a_n}{n} \to a$

This is a corollary of Cesaro's theorem.

$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \to L$ thus $\log{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}=\log{x_{n+1}-\log{x_n}} \to \log{L}$

So from the corollary we have that $$\frac{\log{x_n}}{n} \to \log{L} \Rightarrow \log{\sqrt[n]{x_n}} \to \log{L} \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{x_n} \to L$$