# Superior limit of n-th roots is less than sup lim of fractions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let's assume the next:

$$x_k \geq 0$$
$$L_1 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{k > n} {x_k}^{\frac{1}{k}} $$
$$L_2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{k > n} \frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} $$

I need to prove: $$ L_1 \leq L_2 $$

My ideas:

1) It looks like test for convergence. (if $ L_1  \le 1 $ or if we test something like {$x_k / (2 * L_1^k)$} )

2) We may try to build counterexample with propety $\forall n \in Nat, {x_k}^{\frac{1}{k}} > \frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} $. It follows that $x_k \le x_2^{k-1}$. Then there is 3 cases $x_2 (>/< / =)1$. What must be next?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Math!

Answer (score 0):

This answer of mine
will give you what you want
by just looking
at the upper bound:

[If $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n)^{1/n}=L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419550/if-lim-n-to-infty-fracx-n1x-n-l-then-lim-n-to-infty-x-n1-n/2419605#2419605)