# Comparison of limsup of two particular sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I'm reviewing my analysis, and have found the following problem on an old exam. I don't know how to solve it, so I'm hoping that, if someone can explain it to me, I can gain some familiarity with a technique that I must be overlooking.

I'm also very happy for any hints anyone may drop in the comments!

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence taking values in the positive real numbers. Prove $$\limsup a_n^{1/n}\leq\limsup \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$$

My main idea is to try to use the inequality $\limsup a_nb_n\leq (\limsup a_n)(\limsup b_n)$ to manipulate this into something nicer, but I can't quite see how to do that, and this may be altogether the wrong approach.

Comment: This is already covered in [Inequality involving $\limsup$ and $\liminf$: $ \liminf(a_{n+1}/a_n) \le \liminf((a_n)^{(1/n)}) \le \limsup((a_n)^{(1/n)}) \le \limsup(a_{n+1}/a_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/) and all the threads that are linked to it.

Comment: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen!