# Show that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}{\sup}\sqrt[n]{x_n}\leq \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim{\sup}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered a problem when doing my real analysis assignment. The question is:

> Assume $x_n>0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}{\sup}\sqrt[n]{x_n}\leq \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim{\sup}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}.$

I have no ideas how to prove it. Can someone help or give a hint about this?

Comment: I'd take logarithms.

Comment: There are you have 2 formulas to calculate radius of convergence. Root formula - Cachee's Formula; Fraction formula - d'Alambier's Formula. But this formulas actually without the "sup" function

Comment: And that's strange. You haven't any expression under 'lim'. n->oo should be here. Under 'sup' you can write something about 'x'

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf.

Comment: Thank you for your comments here, I 'll check it.