# $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sqrt[n]{n\cdot(n+1)\cdots(2n)}$

Tags: real-analysis

It tried to solve this limit

$$    \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n\cdot(n+1)\cdots(2n)}}{n}$$
$   \frac{\sqrt[n]{n\cdot(n+1)\cdots(2n)}}{n} = \sqrt[n]{\frac {2n!n}{n!}} \frac{1}{n} \sim \sqrt[n]{\frac { 
 \sqrt {2 \pi  2 n} (\frac {2n}{e})^ {2n}n }{\sqrt {2 \pi   n} (\frac {n}{e})^ {n} }} \frac{1}{n} = 
\sqrt[n]{\frac { 
 \sqrt {2 } (\frac {2n}{e})^ {n}(\frac {2n}{e})^ {n}n }{ (\frac {n}{e})^ {n} }} \frac{1}{n} = 2^{\frac{1}{2n}} \frac{4}{e}n^{\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow \frac{4}{e}$

Is it right?

Comment: Yes. It is: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+1%2Fn*%28%28%282n%29%21n%29%2F%28n%21%29%29%5E%281%2Fn%29

Comment: Use the result that if $a_n>0$ and $a_{n+1}/a_n\to L$ then $a_{n} ^{1/n}\to L$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Riemann Integral to compute the limit.
Since
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\frac{\sqrt[n]{n(n+1)...(2n)}}{n}\\
&=&\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(1+\frac kn)\\
&=&\int_0^1\ln(1+x)dx\\
&=&2\ln2-1
\end{eqnarray}
one has
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n(n+1)...(2n)}}{n}=e^{2\ln2-1}=\frac{4}{e}. $$

Comment: (+1) related to [Riemann Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, we can also use [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69386/505767)

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to L \implies \sqrt[n]{a_n}\to L$$

then by

$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{n\cdot(n+1)\cdots(2n)}{n^n}}$$

we have

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdots(2n+2)}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{n\cdot(n+1)\cdots(2n)}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n(n+1)}\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n} \to \frac 4 e$$

therefore $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to \frac 4 e $.

Answer (score 1):

Using you way
$$\prod_{i=0}^n (n+i)=\frac{(2 n)!}{(n-1)!}$$
$$a_n=\frac 1n \sqrt[n]{\frac{(2 n)!}{(n-1)!}}\implies \log(a_n)=\frac 1n\log((2n)!)-\frac 1n\log((n-1)!)-\log(n)$$
Now, using Stirling approximation
$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({p}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$apply it twice and continue with Taylor series to get
$$\log(a_n)=(2 \log (2)-1)+\frac{\log (2)}{2 n}-\frac{1}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=\frac{4}{e}+\frac{\log (4)}{e n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Answer (score 1):

And, of course, more generally.

Let

$\begin{array}\\
f_k(n)
&=\dfrac{\sqrt[kn]{\prod_{j=1}^{kn}(n+j)}}{n}\\
g_k(n)
&=\ln(f_k(n))\\
&=\frac1{kn}\sum_{j=1}^{kn}\ln(n+j)-\ln(n)\\
&=\frac1{kn}\sum_{j=1}^{kn}(\ln(n)+\ln(1+\frac{j}{n}))-\ln(n)\\
&=\frac1{kn}(kn\ln(n)+\sum_{j=1}^{kn}\ln(1+\frac{j}{n}))-\ln(n)\\
&=\ln(n)+\frac1{kn}\sum_{j=1}^{kn}\ln(1+\frac{j}{n})-\ln(n)\\
&=\frac1{k}\frac1{n}\sum_{j=1}^{kn}\ln(1+\frac{j}{n})\\
&\to \frac1{k}\int_0^{k}\ln(1+x)dx\\
&= \frac1{k}((x+1)\ln(1+x)-x)|_0^{k}\\
&= \frac1{k}((k+1)\ln(1+k)-k)\\
&= (1+1/k)\ln(1+k)-1\\
\end{array}
$

If $k=1$ this is
$2\ln(2)-1
\approx 0.3863
$.

For large $k$ this is about
$\ln(1+k)-1
$
so
$f_k(n)
\approx \dfrac{1+k}{e}
$.

Comment: Nice generalization, for sure.

Comment: And nobody commented that I left out the initial factor of $n$, which, of course, doesn't affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n(n+1)\dots(2n-1)}}{n}$$

$$
\frac{1}{n}\exp\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{\log(n+1)}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\exp\left(\frac{\log n}{n}+\frac{\log (n+1)}{n}+\dots +\frac{\log(2n-1)}{n}\right)
$$

If we can get form like $$\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log(1+i/n) \right)=\exp(\int_1^2\ln(1+i)di)\implies e^{?}$$

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\log(n)+\log(\frac{n+i}{n})\right)=\frac{1}{n}(n-1+1)\log n+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\log(1+\frac{i}{n})
$$
Find limit when $n\to\infty$, that's Riemann wanted. The next step we can calculate integral
$$\exp\left(\int_0^1\ln(1+t)dt\right)=\frac{4}{e}$$
That's becaues $a_n=\frac{i}{n},i\to n-1$ has upper bound and lower bound, substitute with $t\in[0,1]$