# Radius of convergence of this complex-numbers power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I would like to calculate the radius of convergence of power series:

f(z)=\sum{n=0}^∞ n!z^(n!)

My mathematics book says that I can calculate it with Cauchy's test (limsup[n→∞] |a_n|^(1/n)).

However, I don't know what to do in order to calculate it.

I would like you to teach me how to calculate it.

Comment: You could instead find $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+1}|/|a_n|$. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf) question.

Comment: If $z=1$ then divergence is obvious. If $z < 1$ ?