# Root Test Stronger than Ratio Test using $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real positive numbers. We wish to prove that $$ \lim \inf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq \lim \inf a_n^{1/n} \leq \lim \sup a_n^{1/n} \leq \lim \sup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

The answer to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf) shows that $\lim \sup a_n^{1/n} \leq \lim \sup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, and it mentions there is a black-box way to obtain $\lim \inf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq \lim \inf a_n^{1/n}$ from the previous inequality. What is it?

Thanks for your help in advance; I have no clue what this black-box method may be.

Comment: *Hint:* Apply $\lim \sup a_n^{1/n} \leq \lim \sup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ to the sequence $1/a_n$.