Prove that $\liminf_i a^{-1}_{i-j}a_i = \liminf_i a_i^{j/i}$ for any sequence $a_i$?
Title pretty much says it all. I saw this claim in some of my lecture notes which says this is a "general fact about sequences".
In full: let $(a_i)_{i \in \Bbb{N}} \subset \Bbb{R}_{> 0}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Prove that we have
$$\liminf_{i \to \infty} a^{-1}_{i-j}a_i \leq \liminf_{i \to \infty} a_i^{j/i}$$
for all $j \in \Bbb{N}$.
My lecture notes say this is a "general fact" but I have no idea how to prove this. I've tried to prove that the inequality holds for every $i \geq j$ or induction on $j$ but to no avail.
Any help is welcome.

This looks like a generalization of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69386/42969
