$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1}}$?

How to evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1}}\ ?$$

I thought about bringing those different fractions in the sum together into a single one, but then we end up in a circular reasoning, as:
$$1 \to 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n+1) = \frac{(n+1)!}{2}$$
$$2 \to 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n+1) = \frac{2(n+1)!}{3}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$n \to n \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot n = \frac{n(n+1)!}{n+1}$$
Thus
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{2} + \frac{2(n+1)!}{3} + \ldots + \frac{n(n+1)!}{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1}$$
So we need a completely different approach.
We know, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} = 1$, so it's an increasing sequence. Thus:
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1} \le \frac{n}{n+1} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1} \quad | \sqrt[n]{}$$
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1}} \le \sqrt[n]{\frac{n}{n+1} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1}} \ \longrightarrow  \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n \cdot 1} = 1 $$
So in the limit, it's bounded from above by $1$.
But how can I show that in the limit, it's also bounded from below by $1$? Is it sufficient to just use the fact, that $\sqrt[n]{C} \to 1$ if $C \ge 1$ (which will be the case already for $n=2$, as $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{7}{6} > 1$)?

For $n\ge2$ you have
$$1\le\frac12+\frac23+\cdots+\frac n{n+1}\le n.$$
Sandwich it between $1$ and $\root n\of n\to1$.

@JyrkiLahtonen Why $\le n$?

@JyrkiLahtonen Is it because every term in that sum is $\le 1$, and as we have $n$ terms, thus $\le 1 \cdot n = n$?

Yes, that is why $\le n$

$\frac{n}{n+1}\to 1$ and since most of those summands will be close to 1 and dwarf any earlier ones as you take $n\to\infty$, the sum might as well be $n$, so you're left with $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$ (as the first comment mentions)

To evaluate these limits with $n$-th roots, the following inequality comes handy.  For a sequence of positive real numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, we have:
$$\liminf\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \liminf\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq \limsup\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq\limsup\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$
See proof here.
Thus, if $\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ exists then it is equal to $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$.
In your case, $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{3}+\ldots+\frac{n}{n+1}$.
Let's evaluate $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Since $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{n+1}{n+2}$, we have:
$\begin{align}\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=1+\lim\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})a_{n}}\end{align}\tag*{}$
We note that $a_n$ diverges to $+\infty$. This is easily observed by noting that summands $\frac{n}{n+1}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. Consequently, $\frac 1{a_n}\to 0$.
Thus, $$\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1=\lim\sqrt[n]{a_n}.\,\blacksquare$$

here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf

@user thank you!

As an alternative, for the lower bound, by AM-GM
$${\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1}}\ge n \sqrt[n]{\frac1{n+1}}$$
therefore
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n+1}} \ge \sqrt[n]n \;\sqrt[n^2]{\frac1{n+1}}\to 1$$


Define the sequence:

$$
u_n = \sqrt[n]{ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+1} }
$$
To deal with the n-th root, take the natural logarithm of $u_n$:
$$
\ln(u_n) = \frac{1}{n} \ln \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+1} \right)
$$

Simplify the sum and approximate $H_n$:

We simplify each term $\frac{k}{k+1}$ as:
$$
\frac{k}{k+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{k+1}
$$
Thus, the sum becomes:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+1} = n + 1 - H_n
$$
where $H_n$ is the harmonic series, $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$.
For large $n$, the harmonic series behaves as:
$$
H_n \sim \ln(n) + \gamma
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Thus, for large $n$, $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ becomes negligible, so:
$$
\ln(n + 1 - H_n) \sim \ln(n)
$$

Limit of the logarithm:

Substitute back into the expression for $\ln(u_n)$:
$$
\ln(u_n) \sim \frac{1}{n} \ln(n)
$$
As $n \to \infty$, we have $\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \to 0$. Therefore, $\ln(u_n) \to 0$.
Since $\ln(u_n) \to 0$, we conclude that:
$$
u_n \to e^0 = 1
$$
Thus, the limit is:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n+1} } = 1
$$
