# Stirling formula $\ln(n!)\approx n \ln(n)-n$ for Fermi-Dirac statistics and Bose-Einstein statistics?

Tags: mathematical-physics

I recall my teacher mentioned that you can only use the Stirling formula with Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics, not in FD or BE statistics, because of large numbers. How can you then approximate $\ln(x!)$ with FD or BE?

**Example approximation with Bose-Einstein statistics**

> *The probability function for Bose-Einstein with $N_i$ particles with $M-1$ walls is*
>
> $$P=\Pi_i \frac{(N_i+M-1)!}{N_i!(M-1)!}$$
>
> *Now my lecture slides for the physics 2062 in Aalto University claims (p.146 [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/tfy-0.2062/materiaali/Tfy-0_2062_opetusmoniste_2012_-_luku_4.pdf))*
>
> $$\ln P \approx \sum_i \left[\left(N_i+M-1\right)\ln\left(N_i+M-1\right)-(N_i+M-1)-N_i \ln(N_i)+N_i\right]-\ln\left(\left(M-1\right)!\right)$$
>
> *where the premise is $\ln(n!)\approx n \ln(n)-n$ but a small err in the constant term, more in the comment.*

Now Stirling formula is not precise with small amount of particles but the teacher still uses it with both fermions and bosons. I am uneasy about this: more accurate approximation with smaller systems of particles?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you ask your teacher?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Better get peer-previewed answers in Math SE, I like it.

Comment: I think there is a small mistake in the step of the example: should it be $i \ln((M-1)!)$ instead (not just $\ln((M-1)!)$? It matters none in the following step when differentiating because of being just a large number but confusing.

Comment: +1 to the question. Quickly reading through the manuscript left me with the impression that in all the cases, whenever the approximate formula $\ln(n!)\approx n\ln n-n$ was used, the numbers $n$ where large enough not to be cause for concern. After all, even though this is quantum physics, the number of particles in the system is very large. The multiplicative constant $\sqrt{2\pi}$ of the factorial does not affect logarithm much, and will drop out when you take partial derivatives. See the derivation of MB on page 133.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive better Stirling-like approximations of the form
$$n! = \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\dfrac{n}{e} \right)^n \left(1 + \dfrac{a_1}n + \dfrac{a_2}{n^2} + \dfrac{a_3}{n^3} + \cdots \right)$$
using [Abel summation technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272523/limit-of-a-sequence-that-tends-to-1-e/272528#272528) (For instance, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates)), where $$a_1 = \dfrac1{12}, a_2 = \dfrac1{288}, a_3 = -\dfrac{139}{51740}, a_4 = - \dfrac{571}{2488320}, \ldots$$
The hard part in Stirling's formula is deriving the $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ leading coefficient. The remaining coefficients $a_k$'s are not hard to obtain.

Posting this as an answer since it was a bit too long for a comment.