# Sequence - Convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to proof the following:

$ \lim\limits_ {n\to\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n} = \frac{1}{e}$

Do you have any hints for me, since I do not know where to start..

Comment: Taking logarithm also helps.

Comment: One way: It is known that for a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive terms, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ exists, then so does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \root n\of {a_n}$ and the two limits are equal (see Lemma 3 [here](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/243series4.pdf)). Apply this to $a_n=n!/n^n$

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171904/limit-of-a-sequence-involving-root-of-a-factorial-lim-n-to-infty-fracn/171942) is a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You will be interested in [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

$n! \sim (\dfrac{n}{e})^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}$

Comment: Hi, looks great, thank you. Let's see what I can do:

Comment: $\frac{^n\sqrt{n!}}{n}$ = $\frac{^n\sqrt{(\frac{n}{e})^{n}*\sqrt{2πn}}}{n}$ = $ \frac{1}{e}*( ^n\sqrt{2πn})  $

Now I can use that $lim (^n\sqrt{n})= 1 $ and therefore the limit is $1/e $?

Comment: @KevinLiebing: Yes, pretty fine. You have to use L'hopitals rule to find the limit of $^n\sqrt{n}$