# Find the limit of a series involving "e"

Tags: calculus, limits

Hey I've been having problem finding the limit of the sequence below

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$

Thanks!

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171904/limit-of-a-sequence-involving-root-of-a-factorial-lim-n-to-infty-fracn).

Comment: Or this one : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201906/showing-that-frac-sqrtnnn-rightarrow-frac1e

Answer (score 2):

The solution I know involves the *p-norms* and the *Gamma function*: in fact let $f: [0, \infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=xe^{-x}$. Since $f$ is positive, continuous, and $0=f(0)=f(\infty)$, we have $\|f\|_\infty = \max f([0,\infty])$; now $f'(x)=(1-x)e^{-x}$ is $0$ for $x=1$, so that $\|f\|_\infty = f(1)=1/e$. Moreover $$\int_0^\infty |f(x)|^p \ dx=\int_0^\infty x^p e^{-px} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^p}{p^p} e^{-t} \frac{dt}{p} = \frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{p^{p+1}}$$ then $$\|f\|_p = \frac{(\Gamma(p+1))^{1/p}}{p p^{1/p}}$$ since $\lim_{p \to \infty} \|f\|_p = \|f\|_{\infty} = 1/e$ and $\lim_{p \to \infty} p^{1/p}=1$, we get $$\lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{(\Gamma(p+1))^{1/p}}{p p^{1/p}} = \frac{1}{e} \Longrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}=\frac{1}{e} $$

I hope that this will help.

Comment: You have been too fast for me ! Cheers.

Comment: Why is it true that $\lim_p \|f\|_p = \|f\|_\infty$?

Comment: I've used a proposition proved on the notes of my professor:

if $\|f\|_\infty = \infty$ or if $f \in L^p(\mu)$ for some $p>0$  then $\|f\|_\infty = \lim_q \|f\|_q$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the simplest approximation for (n!) that is to say Log[n!] = n Log[n] - n
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation.
Taking logarithms, you will easily show that the limit is 1/e as shown by Dedalus.