# Computing $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}$

Tags: analysis, limits

How do you compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}\;?$$

I know that the answer is $\dfrac{1}{e}$ by plugging it into WolframAlpha, but I have no idea how to get there.

Comment: This has been posted several times recently. I'll look for a recent example.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1231638). In a comment to that question are three other originals listed.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: nice use of that unilateral axe! I see that your example is listed in my comment to the question I linked to.

Comment: I didn't realize I had the power to unilaterally axe. I just marked it as duplicate like I have so many times before. @robjohn

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: actually, it *was* the Community User that closed it. See [this announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes).

Answer (score 0):

[From DeMoivre's formula (Stirling)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixm65p4rxbxpf82/DeMoivre_formula_and_Striling_formula.pdf?dl=0), we have
$$n! \sim C \sqrt{n} \left(\dfrac{n}e\right)^{n}$$
We hence obtain
$$\dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n} \sim \dfrac1e$$