# Which is larger $(101!)^{100}$ or $(100!)^{101}$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, exponentiation, factorial

I am supposed to tell which one of $(101!)^{100}$ and $(100!)^{101}$ is larger. I am trying to use the behavior of the function $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ as is a standard technique to dealing with questions of this sort. Here is what I have so far.

$$\begin{aligned}(101!)^{100!}&\lt (100!)^{101!}\\ (101!)^{100} &\lt (100!)^{101\times 100}\end{aligned}$$

Any ideas on how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Do whatever cancellations you can and you will get the answer easily.

Comment: There's a factorial in the power as well?

Comment: @Gray_Rhino No, there isn't.

Comment: @ParasKhosla But in the body of your post, you've used factorial in the power

Comment: @Ak19 He's trying to solve it using $f(x) = x^{1/x}$, that is why.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892518/prove-nth-root-of-n-is-less-than-n1-th-root-of-n1-sqrtnn-lt-sq), where $n = 100$, and raising both sides by $100 \cdot 101$ gives you this inequality. I am linking to the abstract duplicate [Inequality from Chapter 5 of the book \*How to Think Like a Mathematician\*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166798/inequality-from-chapter-5-of-the-book-how-to-think-like-a-mathematician) because it is much more well-known.

Comment: Hint : $101!^{101}$ is $101^{101}$ times  $100!^{101}$ Compare $101^{101}$ with $101!$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well

$$(101!)^{100}\cdot (101!)=\color{green}{(101!)^{101}}$$
while:
$$(100!)^{101}\cdot (101)^{101}=\color{green}{(101!)^{101}}$$

the one you have to multiply by the larger number is smaller

Answer (score 9):

Simplify:
\begin{align}
\frac{(101!)^{100}}{(100!)^{101}}&=\frac{(100!\times 101)^{100}}{(100!)^{100}\times(100!)}\\
&=\frac{(100!)^{100}\times 101^{100}}{(100!)^{100}\times(100!)}\\
&=\frac{101^{100}}{100!}
\end{align}
Now,
$$\frac{101^{100}}{100!}=\frac{101\times101\times101\times\dots_{100\mathrm{~times}}}{100\times99\times98\times\dots2\times1}=\frac{101}{100}\times\frac{101}{99}\times\frac{101}{98}\times\dots\frac{101}{2}\times\frac{101}{1}>1.$$
You get

> $$\frac{(101!)^{100}}{(100!)^{101}}=\frac{101^{100}}{100!}>1\Rightarrow(101!)^{100}>(100!)^{101}$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$A_n=\big[(n+1)!\big]^n \qquad \text{and}\qquad B_n=\big[n!\big]^{n+1}$$
$$R_n=\frac{A_n}{B_n}=\frac{\big[(n+1)!\big]^n } {\big[n!\big]^{n+1} }$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(R_n)=n \log ((n+1)!)-(n+1) \log (n!)$$ Use Stirling approximation and continue with Taylor expansions
$$\log(R_n)=n+\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi  n)\right)-\frac{7}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$R_n\sim\frac{e^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}} $$

For $n=100$, the above would give $R_{100}\sim 2.92\times 10^{42}$ while the exact value would be $2.90\times 10^{42}$