# Show that $\sqrt[7]{7!}<\sqrt[8]{8!}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, factorial

I have to show that
$$\sqrt[7]{7!}<\sqrt[8]{8!}$$
I've already tried raising both sides to $7\cdot8$ and got
$$(7!)^8<(8!)^7$$
and, after a few computations, I obtained
$$7!<8^7$$
What should I do to prove the above result? Should I use another approach from the beginning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inequality from Chapter 5 of the book \*How to Think Like a Mathematician\*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166798/inequality-from-chapter-5-of-the-book-how-to-think-like-a-mathematician)