# show that $\lim\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\dots x_n}=\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given a sequence of positive numbers $(x_n)$ with $\lim x_n=\alpha$
>   show that $$\lim\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\dots x_n}=\alpha$$

I'm not sure about how to proof it, but if each $x_n\to\alpha$ then $x_1 x_2\dots x_n\to a^n$
so $$\lim\sqrt[n]{x_1 x_2\dots x_n}=\sqrt[n]{a^n}=a$$

How I can proof it?

Comment: your intuition is right, try proving it using epsilons and deltas

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770959/if-x-n-to-x-then-sqrtnx-1x-2-cdots-x-n-to-x?rq=1; This actually appears on "Related" part on the right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cesàro mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) gives that if $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a real sequence converging to $A$ and for every $n\geq 1$ we have $\beta_n=\frac{\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_n}{n}$, then $\{\beta_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a real sequence converging to $A$, too.

So you just have to consider $\alpha_n=\log x_n$ and derive from $\alpha_n\to \log\alpha$ that
$$ \beta_n = \log\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n} \to \log\alpha, $$
hence $\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n}\to \alpha$ by exponentiating back.