# What is This Limit Result Known As?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $\{ a_{n} \}_{1}^{\infty}$ be a positive sequence with limit A ($n \rightarrow \infty$). Then
\begin{equation} 
A = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\{ \sqrt[n]{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3} \cdots a_{n}}  \right\}.
\end{equation}
Any help (with a reference or web page link) would be much appreciated ! I don't need a derivation, but simply want to know if the result is named after anyone.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/770959/42969

Comment: Anyway, a "do it for me" question, showing no effort, is generally considered as low-quality, and closed without an answer.

Comment: I've actually spent quite a bit of time on the web looking for this result. I wouldn't have posted the question otherwise. Why so prickly ? I simply want to know if the results is a named one (maybe after Cauchy ?).

Comment: To help with your searches, you could try using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.