# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_1 a_2 \dotsm a_{2n+1} }$ assuming $a_n >0, \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

I'm aware that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \dotsm a_n} = a$, as shown by [If $(x_n) \to x$ then $(\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}) \to x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/770959/124047).

My question is, what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_1 a_2 \dotsm a_{2n+1} }$?

Assuming $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a > 0$, I think we have

$$
\displaystyle
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_1 a_2 \dotsm a_{2n+1} }
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_1 a_2 \dotsm a_{2n} } \sqrt[2n]{a_{2n+1}} \\
& = a \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_{2n+1}} 
\end{align}
$$

My question then becomes:

- what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_{2n+1}} $?
- does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_{2n+1}} $ exist?
- if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n > 0$, is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_{2n+1}} $ simply $1$, because $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{a_{2n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = 1$ ?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt[2n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_{2n+1}}=\exp\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\log\sqrt[2n+1]{a_1a_2\cdots a_{2n+1}}\right)$.

Comment: Alternatively, $\frac{1}{2}a < a_{2n + 1}  < 2a$ for sufficiently large $n$.