# Why is $\lim_{n \to +\infty }{\sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}} =\lim_{n \to +\infty}{a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Solving some problems regarding limits and sequence convergence, i stumbled upon a task, and it's solution relies on, and i quote: "We now use a well-known theorem :
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty }{\sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n}} = \lim_{n \to +\infty}{a_n}$$

This isn't really intuitive (at least to me) and I don't know how to prove it.
The original task was to find the limit of 
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty }{\sqrt[n]{\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{1}\bigg{)} \bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{2}\bigg{)}^2 \ldots \bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^n}} $$
which of course, using the expression above is just $e$.

Comment: may I ask you which book you found this task in? I'm asking because it appeared among our exercise tasks and I still don't know how to prove this theorem (if it really is a theorem).  It would really help me because I'm a first-year student and there are a very few books available in my mother-tongue.

Comment: See also: [If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$ and $a_n>0$ for all $n$, then we have $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt\[n\]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}=a $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/460706) and [If $(x_n) \to x$ then $(\sqrt\[n\]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}) \to x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/770959).

Comment: The hypothesis $a_n>0$ should be stated.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3694210/721644) is a possible duplicate of yours.

Comment: You need to assume more than just $a_n\gt0$ for all $n$. For example, if

$$a_n=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\
2&\text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}=\sqrt2$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the logarithm of both sides. Then you want to prove

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n a_i = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n.$$

This is a standard result about [Cesàro means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean).

Answer (score 3):

Take the log of the $n$-root, and applied the Cesaro theorem to it, showing that it will converge to the log of $(a_n)_n$'s limit. Take the exp to finish.

Comment: of course, continuity of log and exp is crucial