# Correct usage of Stolz-Cesaro theorem in finding a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is this solution correct?

I've seen this solution before, but I don't know why it is so. And which rule?

The task is to find: $\omega=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}\right)$

I know that this $\lim$ equals $\frac{1}{e},$ but do you see if this solution is correct or not?

Solution is :

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}\right)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left((n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}-n\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^{n}}}\right)$

$=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^{n}}}$

$=\frac{1}{e}$

Notes & suggestions of mine:

I think he uses Stolz-Cesaro theorem:

See that

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}$

Chosen $a_{n}=n\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}$

and $b_{n}=n$  clearly $b_{n}$ goes to $+\infty$ and $a_{n}$ goes to $+\infty$ because $n.\frac{1}{e}=+\infty$

we obtain:

$\omega=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$

Then use Cauchy-d'Alembert

$=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^{n}}}=\frac{1}{e}$

Is my explanation O.K.? 
May I ask for a correction?

Any remark ?

Comment: Yes, that is how that argument can go using Stolz's.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2020153/72031

Answer (score 2):

The use of Cesaro-Stolz as you mention is invalid. In application of Cesaro-Stolz the existence of limit of $\dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$ is a hypotheses and not the conclusion. Thus you have tried to use Cesaro-Stolz in reverse which does not work.

Comment: Why , what about reserve stolz-Cesaro ?

Comment: @EllenEllen: converse of that theorem does not hold in general and therefore your approach is wrong.

Comment: But why i use it this method in many limits and I get always  correct answer !!

Comment: @EllenEllen: Here is a fact from rules of logic: a wrong approach does not guarantee wrong answer. Hence don't be charmed by the illusion of wrong approaches. They may fail when you need them most.

Comment: @EllenEllen : Cesaro-Stolz is one of my favorite tools but it needs to be used in proper manner.

Comment: @EllenEllen : your use of Cauchy-d'Alembert at the end is correct. Also note that Cauchy-d'Alembert follows from Cesaro-Stolz.

Comment: ok thanks so this solution wrong ! , but see that $B\implies A$ sometimes we see if $A$ correct then B also correct ? So I think here we see if $\lim\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$ then $\lim\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}=L$ ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Stolz-Bolzano theorem is necessary here (:  , but I agree with everything you explained. Nevertheless, I'll write down everything in detail for everyone who might have not understood similar proofs to other (similar) posts.

Since $n\to\infty$, $n+1$ behaves (more or less) similarly:

Inductively: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}}$$
$$\implies\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}\right)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left((n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}-n\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^{n}}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg((n+1)\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}-n\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}\Bigg)=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$$ 
As proven here:
[Why is $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty }{\sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n}} =\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}{a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119379/why-is-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtna-1-a-2-ldots-a-n-lim-limits)

You can apply the Cauchy-D'Alembert criterion already here:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n(n+1)}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You can't replace one expression by another in this manner. - 1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thank you for the remark. May I ask if this kind of solution is allowed at all in some cases? I thought I could do this since I had just a term of a sequence, not sum or product. I appreciate your comment because I also learn from that and benefit from it and gain more experience as a first-year student.

Comment: Ok one can't leave the fundamentals. Thus you can't replace $A$ by $B$ unless $A=B$. I have provided some details in this answer which allows for certain manipulation while evaluating limits: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, thank you very much for help and understanding!