# If $\frac{a_{n+1}}{na_{n}}\to a>0,$ then $\frac{(n+1)^2}{\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}}-\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}\to?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We have a strictly positive sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge1}.$ We know
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{na_{n}}=a>0.$$ What is the value of:  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}}-\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}\right)?$$
I tried using the theorem when we have all sequence terms positive and we know the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_{n}$ is equal to $L,$ then the limit of square root of rank $n$ of $a_{n}$ is that $L.$ I got that $L = na.$ Then I tried to put that $L$ in the main limit we want to calculate and got $2/a,$ but my teacher said the proof is wrong.

Comment: Please type the relevant information into the question itself rather than including an image, which messes up search engines and people who use screen readers.

Comment: I am new to this platform and I dont know latex. I will try to put the information with ASCII characters.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "square root of rank $n$" -- you mean $n$-th root. Also, how do you get $L=n \cdot a$ form that? It does not make sense because $L$ cannot depend on $n$.

Comment: We cant multiply that limit propriety they gave us with n to say limit of a_{n+1}/a_{n} is n×a?

Comment: No, we cannot. E.g. $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n =0$ does not imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 \stackrel{??}=n\cdot 0 =0$. You are not just multiplying with $n$ here, you take the $n$ out of the limit, which is almost always a bad and wrong idea. (Note that multiplying both sides of my example with $n$ actually gives $n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = n \cdot 0 = 0$ which is still true, albeit useless.)

Comment: I was talking about multiplying the propriety they gave us with the limit as n go infinity of n so we will get limit as n go to infinity of a_{n+1} / a_{n} = the limit as n go infinity of ( n × a )

Comment: And I just told you you cannot do that, just with a simple example. To take yours: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{n a_n} = a$ does **not** imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{ a_n} = n \cdot a$. Sure you can multiply both sides with $n$, but that gives $n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{n a_n} = n \cdot a$ for all $n$, which seems useless. You cannot "move the $n$ out of (or into) the limit".

Comment: I understand, thank you. So we need somehow to get a{n+1}/(n×a_{n}) inside the main limit somehow. But I tried and did not get something nice by forcing.

Comment: We can't use that theorem as we do not know $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges.  In fact we know it can not converge, because if it did we would have $\lim \frac {a_{n+1}}{na_n} = \lim \frac 1nL = 0 \ne a = \lim \frac {a_{n+1}}{na_n}$.  SO $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ does not converge.

Comment: Yes I understand. I feel like the sequence is similar to the factorial sequence. I feel like we need to use somehow Traian Lalescu's limit with factorials but I dont know how.

Comment: See a more general result at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4485844/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$p_n:=\frac{n^{2n}}{a_n}.$$
We are looking for
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}}-\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n+1]{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt[n]{p_n}\right).$$
We know that [if $\frac{p_{n+1}}{np_n}\to p>0,$ then $\sqrt[n+1]{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt[n]{p_n}\to\frac pe.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457308)

Here,
$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{np_n}=\frac{na_n}{a_{n+1}}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{2n+2}\to p:=\frac{e^2}a$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}}-\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}\right)=\frac ea.$$

Comment: I know who downvoted and I find this childish attitude pathetic.

Comment: In a math olympiad problem do we need to prove that limit p/e or we can just use it as a lemma

Comment: I think we need to prove it.

Comment: there exist any way to prove that with lalescu limit and without stirling aproximation?

Comment: I found another solution without stirling and lalescu only with Cauchy-Dalambert and Euler sequence wich is shorter and nicer.

Comment: Meanwhile, I [answered positively to your previous comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4588096/386889). If your "other solution" is also for that limit p/e, can you add it similarly over there?

Comment: I solved for this problem I didnt use p/e

Answer (score 1):

Here is a treatment of the Lalescu types of limits.

> **[Theorem (O. Carja)](http://www.recreatiimatematice.ro/arhiva/nota/RM22003CARJA.pdf?i=1):** Suppose $(a_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence of positive numbers such that 
> (i) $\lim_n\frac{p_n}{n}=p>0$
> (ii) $\lim_n\big(\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}\big)^n=q\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+$.
> Then
> $$L=\lim_n(p_{n+1}-p_n)$$ exists and $L=p\log q$.

This result is not difficult to prove using basic results from Calculus. A simple and short proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4811292/121671)

To solve the problem the OP, define
$$p_n:=\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}$$
(i) Then
$$\frac{p_n}{n}=\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{a_n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e}{a}$$
for $$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{a_{n+1}}\frac{a_n}{n^n}=\frac{na_n}{a_{n+1}}\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big)^n\frac{n+1}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e}{a}.$$
(ii) Also,
$$\Big(\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}\Big)^n=\frac{(n+1)^{2n}}{n^{2n}}\frac{na_n}{a_{n+1}}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}}{n+1}\frac{n+1}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^2\frac{1}{a}\frac{a}{e}=e.
$$

Applying the theorem above yields the desire limit
$$\lim_n(p_{n+1}-p_n)=\frac{e}{a}\log e=\frac{e}{a}$$

Comment: Wasn't aware that there was a specific theorem to deal with such limits. I mostly used the same proof strategy in deal with such limits. An instance is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4485844/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I just tried my luck with the problem in your [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4816471/121671) and Carja's result worked like a charm.