# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{n!}{n^n} \right)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I go about evaluating this?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \dfrac{n!}{n^n} \right)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: This must have been asked many times before. Have you done a search before asking?

Comment: Essentially [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn).

Comment: Or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201906/showing-that-frac-sqrtnnn-rightarrow-frac1e).

Answer (score 4):

Recall from [Stirling's Approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) that,
$$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} n^n e^{-n}$$
$$\therefore\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{n!}{n^n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} n^n }{n^n e^n}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-1} (2 \pi)^{1/2n}n^{1/2n}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 2):

Apply the theorem which says that if $a_n\to L$ then $\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdots a_n} \to L$ to the limit $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} \to e$.

Comment: I like this one better because proving the validity of stirling's approximation is not so fast.

Comment: Of course the theorem being used is also not so easy to prove, notice than it works for **positive** real sequences.

Comment: Here is a possible way to prove the theorem , you have to prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\log{a_n}}{n}$ converges to $\log(L)$. but of course $\log(a_n)$ converges to $\log(L)$ so you have reduced it to proving if $a_n\to L$ then $\frac{a_1+a_2\dots a_n}{n}\to L$ which is straightforward.

Comment: @dREaM The theorem is easier (much easier)  than the stirling approx. And not really that hard its just $\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_n}{n}\to L$  applied to $\ln a_n$

Comment: yeah, I gave a small sketch of proof above, I agree this is a more direct approach.

Comment: @dREaM We are saying the same thing, I was writing my comment and didnt see yours before I submitted.