# radius of convergence of power series n!z^n/n^n

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Please help me find radius of convergence of the following: check the attached picture to have a better image
\sum n=0 to infinity n! z^n / n^n
I used Hadamard's formula 1/R=lim sup|an|^1/n didnt know how to proceed is the radius = infinity? or 1/e plz help
[image]

Comment: Hint: Use starling's formula to approx. n! and calculate the limit.

Comment: I've never heard starling's formula, so please show solution if you know I will deeply appreciate it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: well I only have to use Hadamard's formula which is the radius of convregence can you please try using it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201906/showing-that-frac-sqrtnnn-rightarrow-frac1e

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the root test with $a_{n}=(n!/n^{n}) z^{n}$ to get
$$
\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}=z\lim\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}
$$

Comment: @user314: Updated with more text that should make it clear.