# is there a root test for the convergence of sequences (not for convergence of series)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been having troubles finding information about the root test for *sequences* (**not series!**) that someone mentioned to me (I was interested in seeing a proof, at least). I've looked for it in many books and online, but could only find information about a root test for series. I have attached an image containing the test - is this genuine or is that person wrong?

[image: Root test for sequences convergence?]

> Root test (D'Alembert test): May $(a_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a sequence with strictly positive terms. If $l\in\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ exists so that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=l$.

Comment: It's true. 
See [these notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/243series4.pdf) of [Pete L. Clark](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark) for a proof.

Comment: By the way, note it's not giving a test for the convergence of $(a_n)$; it's just saying that if the limit of the ratios exists, then so does the limit of the roots and in this case the two limits are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, David, but aren't the notes about series? I'm looking for information about the convergence of sequences (not series), I will edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: See Lemma 3 on page 3 (it applies to any sequence of positive terms).

Comment: I answered too soon, I should have read more carefully! Thank you so much, this answeres my question. Would you post it as an answer for me to be able to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true. See [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243series4.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130728110356/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243series4.pdf)) of [Pete L. Clark](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark) for a proof (Lemma 3 on page 3).  Another proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287932/convergence-of-ratio-test-implies-convergence-of-the-root-test?rq=1) at MSE.

(By the way, note the result is  not giving a test for the convergence of$(a_n)$; it's just saying that if the limit of the ratios exists, then so does the limit of the roots and in this case the two limits are the same. )

Comment: Thank you, once again, for your fast and helpful answer!

Comment: @oana You're welcome.

Comment: As far sa I can tell, the notes linked in the post eventually became one part of  the text [Honors Calculus](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf). (Just in case, here is a [Wayback Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220503044808/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf)).