# Use Binet's formula for the Fibonacci numbers to show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} = \phi.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Use Binet's formula for the Fibonacci numbers to show $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} = \phi.$$

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: See the similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728973/fibonacci-numbers-and-golden-ratio-phi-lim-sqrtnf-n?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution if you do not know Binet's formula.
Let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$. Thus
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{u_{n+2}}{u_{n+1}}$$
$$\implies a_{n+1} = \frac{u_{n+1}+u_n}{u_{n+1}}=1 + \frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}.$$
Therefore
$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}\right) = 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}} = 1 + \frac{1}{L}.$$
Thus
$$L = 1 + 1/L \implies L^2 - L - 1 = 0.$$
Taking the positive root, we have $L=(1+\sqrt{5})/2 = \phi.$

Comment: why we take the positive root only?

Comment: @hopefully because $u_{n+1}/u_n \geq 1$ for $n \geq 1$ and the ratio cannot be negative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Binet formula write $$u_n=\frac{
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^n-\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^n}{2^n\sqrt{5}}=\frac{
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^n}{2^n\sqrt{5}}\Big(1-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^n\Big)$$

Look how small is the factor $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}\approx -0.382$.

Comment: Could you provide more details please?

Comment: @hopefully. Make $n=10$ and use your pocket calculator to see that  the factor $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^{10}$ is  $0.000066$. Quite small, isn't it ?

Comment: And what does it mean for the factor to be small ? what is the relation between this and $\phi$?

Comment: @hopefully. May be that, when $n$ is large, you can neglect it. This gives you the asymptotics of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: How can I prove that it equals $\phi$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}}{\phi^n-\psi^n}=\phi\frac{1-\left(\dfrac\psi\phi\right)^{n+1}}{1-\left(\dfrac\psi\phi\right)^n}.$$

As
$$\left|\dfrac\psi\phi\right|<1,$$ the ratio (quickly) tends to $1$.