# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(F_{n})=\log(\varphi)$, where $(F_{n})$ is the Fibonacci sequence and $\varphi$ is the golden ratio

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Im calculating the topological entropy of a certain dynamical system. In this calculation I encounter the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(F_{n}),$$ where $(F_{n})$ is the Fibonacci sequence ($F_{1}:=1$, $F_{2}:=1$, $F_{n+2}:=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$) and $\varphi$ is the golden ratio ($=1.6180\ldots$). How do I show that this limit converges to $\log(\varphi)$?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728973/fibonacci-numbers-and-golden-ratio-phi-lim-sqrtnf-n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\varphi$$
is a well known result. We also have that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n^{1/n}=\varphi$$
because of the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf) that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$
when the latter limit exists. So we can say that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log{(F_n)}}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log{\left(F_n^{1/n}\right)}=\log{\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n^{1/n}\right)}=\log{(\varphi)}$$
because $\log{(x)}$ is continuous when $x=\varphi$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\varphi$, we have by continuity

$$\lim_{n\to \infty
}\bigl(\log F_{n+1} -\log F_n\bigr)=\log\varphi.$$

Now use *Cesàro's theorem* and the fact that the series $\bigl(\log F_{n+1} -\log F_n\bigr)$ is a telescoping series.

Answer (score 0):

$$F_n=\frac{a^n-b^n}{\sqrt{5}}, a= \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, b=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}, a>|b|$$ So when $n$ is large $$\frac{a^n-2b^n}{\sqrt{5}}< F_n <\frac{2 a^n}{\sqrt{5}} $$ Next, $$ \ln a +\frac{1}{n} \ln \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}+ \ln[1-2 \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n] < \frac{1}{n} \ln (F_n) < \log a +\frac{1}{n} \ln \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}.$$ 
As $|b/a|<1$ the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ of both sides goes to $$\ln a.$$