# simplify expression to find a limit

Tags: algebra-precalculus

find the limit of $\large\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ using the ratio test

$$\Large \frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)^\frac{1}{n+1}}{\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^\frac{1}{n}}$$

I have added $\frac{n}{n}$ and $\frac{n+1}{n+1}$ to both components and got:

$$\Large\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}}{\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)}}$$

and then

$$\Large\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}}{\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}}+\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}}{\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$$
$$\Large=\left(\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{(\frac{n^n}{n!})}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}+\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}}{\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$$
$$\Large=\left(\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{(\frac{n^n}{n!})}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}+\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}}{\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$$
$$=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n+\Large\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)^\frac{n}{n(n+1)}}{\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$$

How to I proceed from here? (the limit is $e$)

Comment: That hurts my eyes.

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta Sorry, thanks to Mattos it was fixed

Comment: It's okay, no problem. Now to read it. :)

Comment: @gbox Use `\left(` and `\right)` for bigger brackets.

Comment: what is the original problem?

Comment: Guessing it was a ratio test attempt on a series judging by its form

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner added the original problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{n^n}{n!}$.

Then $\displaystyle\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to e$,

so $\displaystyle\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}=(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\to e$

Comment: How did you get this? as $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{(n+1)!^\frac{1}{n+1}}$

Comment: If the sequence you started with is $c_n$, say, then $a_n=(c_n)^n$.

Comment: ok but in my case its need to be $(\frac{n^n}{(n!)})^\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Exactly - Your sequence is $(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, and I'm using that if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to L$, then $(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\to L$.

Comment: what theorem is it?

Comment: Here is one reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287932  See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386