# Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=l$ imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=l$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, examples-counterexamples, radicals

Consider a series $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n$. How can I show the following?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=l \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=l$$

Comment: It works in the opposite direction. See, for example [Convergence of Ratio Test implies Convergence of the Root Test](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/287932) and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/287932).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because it's not true.  For example, take
$$a_n=\cases{4^n&if $n$ is even\cr2\times4^n\quad&if $n$ is odd.\cr}$$
Then
$$a_n^{1/n}=\cases{4&if $n$ is even\cr4\times2^{1/n}\quad&if $n$ is odd\cr}$$
which has limit $l=4$.  But
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\cases{8&if $n$ is even\cr2\quad&if $n$ is odd\cr}$$
which has no limit.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example. Could I prove the statement if I suppose in advance that **both** $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ and  $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$ do exist?

Comment: The comment from @MartinSleziak answers this for you doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_n=0$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=0$$

but

$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ is indeterminate.